# Metadata file '.dll' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0

I am working on a WPF, C# 3.0 project, and I get this error:

```
Error 1 Metadata file
'WORK=- \Tools\VersionManagementSystem\BusinessLogicLayer\bin\Debug
\BusinessLogicLayer.dll' could not be found C:\-=WORK=- \Tools
\VersionManagementSystem\VersionManagementSystem\CSC VersionManagementSystem
```

This is how I reference my usercontrols:

```
xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:VersionManagementSystem"
<vms:SignOffProjectListing Margin="5"/>
```

It happens after every failed build. The only way I can get the solution to compile is to comment out all my user controls and re-build the project, and then I uncomment the usercontrols and everything is fine.

I have checked build orders and dependencies configurations.

As you can see, it seems to have truncated the DLL file's absolute path... I have read that there is a bug with the length. Is this a possible problem?

It's very annoying and having to comment, build, and uncomment, the build is becoming extremely tiresome.

Comment: I had a similar problem (getting the same error that is indicated at the title) and handled it by cleaning and rebuilding the project. To correctly reference other projects, I do have no idea..

Comment: I have marked Matt's answer as it seems to have worked for most people however this did not resolve my original issue. I still think it is related to the Windows max path limit. See my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Metadata file '...\Release\project.dll' could not be found in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898559/metadata-file-release-project-dll-could-not-be-found-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I tried all the answers above and unfortunately nothing worked in my case. I encountered with 2 errors 1. Missing .dll file 2. Method already defined at another place with same parameters

I have cleared the second error first by removing the function which has been duplicated at another place. My first error - that is .dll file missing has solved on its own.

I want to say if you have more than single error along with .dll missing file error! Please try to solve the other errors first. May be .dll error solves on it own!

Comment: We also get the metadata file '.dll' not found issue when you are referring a project dll which built on higher version .Net framework than your current project.

Comment: The solution to similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490857/visual-studio-getting-error-metadata-file-xyz-could-not-be-found-after-edi worked for me.

Comment: The fact that this thing still happens in 2018 pains me a lot. I'm not even sure how I manage to fix it. Its like a VS thing or something.

Comment: Something else to try, I fixed all the other errors in the solution and this problem went away.

Comment: This worked for me in VS2019 .Net Core, ASP.Net Core solution. Open a PowerShell console in the same location of the solution. type **dotnet restore** and then **dotnet build**, the solution will be built and now it can be built from Visual Studio IDE too. None of the other solution given worked for me.

Comment: In my case, none of the answers helped. So I reviewed error by error in the following way. Example: ProjectA.dll could not be found. In the same line it is listed from which other projects it is referenced. say RefProject.csproj. In solution explorer, go to "Dependencies" and remove there the ProjectA reference. Do that for all errors. Then, perform a clean+rebuild getting more errors. Most of them are due to missing reference. Re-Add them using Intellisense, and process error by error. In the end the solution will compile again. It was likely caused by corrupt csproj file metadata.

Comment: One of my projects was unloaded. Right clicking to reload in Solution explorer worked.

Answer (score 1195, accepted):

I just had the same problem. Visual Studio isn't building the project that's being referenced.

### Written Instructions:

1. Right click on the solution and click Properties.
2. Click Configuration on the left.
3. Make sure the check box under "Build" for the project it can't find is checked. If it is already checked, uncheck, hit apply and check the boxes again.
4. (Optional) You had to do it for both Release and Debug modes on the solution properties.

### Screen capture Instructions:

- They say a picture is worth a thousand words. Click on the GIF to zoom in, and hopefully it will be easy to follow:

[image: Gif Instructions]

Comment: Simble uncheck/check didn't solve issue so I've had to do next steps:
- clean solution
- uncheck all build checkboxes
- restart VS
- check all build checkboxes
- build solution

Comment: The other thing to do is check each of the project dependencies, for some reason it wasn't setting this automagically. Solution Properties -> Common Properties -> Project Dependencies.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be automatically set when you add a project reference?

Comment: Dumbest thing ever. I unchecked/rechecked for the release config, because it said it was getting the error in the `release/bin` folder. That didn't fix it. I did the same thing for the debug configuration and then the `release/bin` error went away. Microsoft 0/10

Comment: This happened to me after updating some NuGet Packages for my solution. Visual Studio was not building the project that was being referenced in the error output, and the intellisense was incorrectly indicating that there were no issues with the project in error. After I built the specific project in error, the intellisense decided to kick in, and at that point, I was able to see the errors in my project. (some methods that I was using had been removed in an updated NuGet Package)

Comment: For me it was also a missing library (Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in my case). that NuGet failed to restore properly when I cloned the solution from version control. I ran update-package -reinstall <package-name> which fixed it. The missing dll errors were a consequence of this, and I failed to scroll down far enough in the Error List to notice ;)

Comment: doing so leads me to an IL merge issue (ilmerge exited with code 1)

Comment: In my case, I had a couple class library projects which were running under lower .NET target frameworks than the main project. Switching them from 4.5 > 4.6 fixed my issue.

Comment: After cleaning my solution Visual Studio 2015 crashed out and restarted. I was subsequently getting this issue; all projects were checked under the solution configuration; unchecking and checking again worked. Very strange!

Comment: For me I needed to update the Target framework(properties -> applictaion tab).  Then the .dll was being created.

Comment: 2017 and this answer is still saving some asses. In one my class libraries a dependency was being shown as "installed", but NugetPackageManager showed that it needed to be installer. Reinstalling solved my issue

Comment: I tried all the solutions but it didn't worked for me. but updating framework version to higher version (in my case 4.6.1) fixed the issue. Actually, it was a newly added dll which required higher framework version in my project.

Comment: In my case, I had to remove the bad reference that was under the References -> Analyzers. As soon as I removed it, I was able to build it properly.

Comment: Doesn't work. All projects already checked for build, and unchecking, saving, checking again, saving doesn't help, either.

Comment: C#7 features in VS2015 were causing this error message for me. (Expressions-bodied member for a setter, specifically) I had to update to VS2017.

Comment: Had 4.5.2 and 4.5 as my project frameworks so I made them both 4.5.2 and then ran Update-Package -reinstall

Comment: Just update all reference package from nuget package manager.After that just restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015.  I did this, but I still had an error I needed to resolve.  It might be worth mentioning that doing this didn't make this error disappear until I resolved the other error.

Comment: I just had an error that was unrelated to all of this. I had an extra `}` at the end of the class file which caused the metadata error.

Comment: This just started happening out of the clue... every project file fails to build, with the only errors being the metadata ones. Nothing seems to work to resolve this.

Comment: This did not work for me. I found the error in my case. It was because I removed the nuget package Mahapps which I was no longer using anywhere so I just wanted to clean up. After I removed it, I got the error without anything indicating the mahapps nuget package. I found out that I had the nuget package in 2 projects, one projectreferencing the other. They had a different version of the package, which might have been the underlying problem. I updated both to the latest version before removing them. That fixed the problem.

Comment: If you have wcf in your project, clean the solution, update their references and Rebuild solution. Restart VS. That fixed my problem!

Comment: Still a bug in VS 2019 and this fix works, as of 12/10/2019. I had to ensure to clean the project first, then just run the project (not rebuild) after this fix.

Comment: this happen due to some existing issues also such as NuGet Packages update wanted,any file mixing etc.Once you fixed the other issues and rebuild then this issue may be sorted.

Comment: This pointed me to the underlying problem, I had put the string interpolation '$' on the wrong side of the '@' , like this:  @$"som text {myVariable}";  when it should be like this: $@"som text {myVariable}"; causing one project not to build and thus other depending projects failed to build.  - When I disabled all project builds and enabled them one by one with the "core / library project" first I got the warnings in output needed to pinpoint the root cause

Comment: it was the solution for me too.  i was getting error like this "metadata file '' could not be found" It doesn't give the file name either.

Comment: Make sure to apply after each check. Unchecking and checking all projects and then applying did not work for me.

Comment: If this doesn't work straight away, consider restarting Visual studio after doing it.
A little heads up, before I restarted my visual studio, I had made some changes, after the restart, I noticed my last few changes were gone, so you might want to copy your changes somewhere temporarily or save them with git

Answer (score 271):

This can still happen in newer versions of Visual Studio (I just had it happen on Visual Studio 2013):

Another thing to try is to close Visual Studio and delete the `.suo` file that is next to the `.sln` file. (It will be re-generated the next time you `Save all` (or exit Visual Studio)).

I've had this problem when adding new projects to the solution on another machine and then pulling the revisions in, but the `.suo` file can be corrupted in other cases as well and lead to very strange Visual Studio behaviour, so deleting it is one of the things I always try.

Note that deleting the `.suo` file will reset the startup project(s) of the solution.

More on the `.suo` file is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx).

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Also worth mentioning is that `.suo` files are hidden. So you'll have to setup your explorer to show hidden files.

Comment: I'm working with Xamarin project and the .suo file is located in the .vs/ folder . I tried deleting it and it didn't solve my problem

Comment: VS2013 - I had to move my TFS Workspace to a different location. After I completed this I started to get this error. Deleting the sou file worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too.  But in Visual Studio 2015, the `.suo` file is both hidden and sits within a hidden `.vs` directory beside the `.sln`.   e.g.:   if the solution file is `c:\foo\mysolution.sln` then look for `c:\foo\mysolution\.vs\mysolution\v14\.suo`

Comment: I had it happen on VS 2015 update 3 and Matt's solutions worked for me.

Comment: I am using VS2017RC and deleting the .suo file in the hidden top level .vs folder worked for me!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved this problem for me on VS 2013, after struggling with it for almost an hour

Comment: In VS2017 the `.suo` has the same path as in @Wyck 's comment. Altough, yours may be in a v15 folder and not v14.

Comment: Closing and opening visual studio helped me. Thanks

Comment: For VS2017, for simplicity, I just deleted the `.vs` hidden folder instead which also deleted the `.suo` file. I reopened the solution, fixed one more unrelated error, and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Still happening in VS 2019 as of today. Marked answer actually worked for me. I just had to make sure I iterated through every configuration type (Release, Debug, etc) and unchecked, apply, rechecked, apply on all of them.

Comment: This worked for me with VS 2019 Community Ed.

Comment: Worked for me. I am using VS 2019

Answer (score 229):

The suggested answer did not work for me. The error is a decoy for another problem.

I found out that I was targeting a slightly different version of .NET and this was flagged as a warning by the compiler, but it was causing building to fail.
This should have been flagged as an error and not a warning.

Comment: I was able to fix by matching the framework for the project to the higher version indicated in the warning message by right clicking on the project > Properties > Application > Target Framework.

Comment: Wow, this fixed it for me. New project was targeting a different .net version. Can't believe there isn't a check for this even in vs2017.

Comment: Worth noting that the problem can go deeper than just the project that is causing problems.  Even if that project is targeting the right framework, if that project depends on another project and the dependent project is targeting a different framework, then it can cause this problem too.

Comment: I think it's useful to point out that you might be able to spot the "decoyed" error by looking in the Ouput window. In my case, **after disabling the build for the highlighted projects** as described in the accepted answer from @Matt_Bro, **I ran the build again and spotted the real problem in the Output window,** since the build was failing **even if no error was displayed in the Error List**.

Comment: In my case it was yet again to do with with Target .NET Framework of the project being older than the one of a referenced assembly. I could visualize the correct error only in the Output window as per my previous comment.

Comment: Using preview versions of .NET Core can also cause this problem. It can be disabled from: Options - Project and Solutions - .NET Core - Use previews of the .NET Core SDK.

Comment: I concur.  I had a project dependency on a 4.7.2 Framework by a 4.8 Framework project.  No error identifying this dependency fail was thrown.

Comment: if you try to open a solution which references to any .NET 6 Or .NET 7 projects in Visual Studio 2019, this error will appear, opening in VS 2022 Fixed it, thank for your answer.

Answer (score 124):

Well, my answer is not just the summary of all the solutions, but it offers more than that.

**Section (1):**

**In general solutions:**

I had four errors of this kind (‘metadata file could not be found’) along with one error saying 'Source File Could Not Be Opened (‘Unspecified error ‘)'.

I tried to get rid of ‘metadata file could not be found’ error. For that, I read many posts, blogs, etc. and found these solutions may be effective (summarizing them over here):

1. Restart Visual Studio and try building again.
2. Go to **'Solution Explorer'**. Right click on Solution. Go to **Properties**. Go to **'Configuration Manager'**. Check if the checkboxes under **'Build'** are checked or not. If any or all of them are unchecked, then check them and try building again.
3. If the above solution(s) do not work, then follow sequence mentioned in step 2 above, and even if all the checkboxes are checked, uncheck them, check again and try to build again.
4. **Build Order and Project Dependencies:**

   Go to **'Solution Explorer'**. Right click on Solution. Go to **'Project Dependencies...'**. You will see two tabs: **'Dependencies'** and **'Build Order'**. This build order is the one in which solution builds. Check the project dependencies and the build order to verify if some project (say 'project1') which is dependent on other (say 'project2') is trying to build before that one (project2). This might be the cause for the error.
5. **Check the path of the missing .dll:**

   Check the path of the missing .dll. If the path contains space or any other invalid path character, remove it and try building again.

   If this is the cause, then adjust the build order.

---

**Section (2):**

**My particular case:**

I tried all the steps above with various permutations and combinations with restarting Visual Studio a few times. But, it did not help me.

So, I decided to get rid of other error I was coming across ('Source File Could Not Be Opened (‘Unspecified error ‘)').

I came across a blog post: *[TFS Error–Source File Could Not Be Opened (‘Unspecified error ‘)](http://www.anujvarma.com/tfs-errorsource-file-could-not-be-opened-unspecified-error/#comment-1539)*

I tried the steps mentioned in that blog post, and I got rid of the error **'Source File Could Not Be Opened (‘Unspecified error ‘)'** and surprisingly I got rid of other errors **(‘metadata file could not be found’)** as well.

---

**Section (3):**

**Moral of the story:**

Try all solutions as mentioned in section (1) above (and any other solutions) for getting rid of the error. If nothing works out, as per the blog mentioned in section (2) above, ***delete the entries of all source files which are no longer present in the source control and the file system from your .csproj file***.

Comment: My problem was Build Order/Project Dependencies. Removing and adding back references from other projects will correct this (I think) but you can just do it yourself as well.

Comment: I faced this problem by down-grading `.NET v4.5` project to `.NET v.4`.

Comment: It's not a summary of all other answers as claimed in the heading. The solution to your particular case does not address the original problem

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy, please read first line of my answer properly. "Well, my answer is not just the summary of all the solutions, but it offers more than that." I myself made it clear that it is not just the summary of other answers. I have given few common strategies that may work (kind of summary) (section 1). But, after that I explained a case where none of these worked and I had to solve the problem by some other way (section 2). So, people can try section 1 first and if they have case similar to mine, they can try section 2.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy, already 56 users have upvoted it. Your downvote brought it down to 55. If it would not have been useful, why would so many users have upvoted it? Please read properly before you comment and think before you downvote.

Comment: Fix any other errors you get; They might silently stop the project building so no dll is created. When I resolved the other error I had, the build completed and all errors went away.

Comment: This might be too obvious, but make sure that the targeted dll's are not already in use via another instance of Visual Studio or by another exe.

Comment: Removing "%" from referenced dll path helped me

Comment: @kkuilla It was too long ago. Unfortunately I dont remember. Since I have not upvote any answers, may be created a clean .NET 4 project and manually moved source files.

Comment: The solution in Section 2 worked for me! I had another error and when I fixed that the others magically dissappeared.

Comment: I had the same issue as Boogier. Had a %20 in my folder name instead of a space and the dll was looking for a space. Spent so much time trying all the other fixes, when the actual one was the simplest.

Comment: My solution path had %20 in the directory path.  That was a cloned repo from Azure DevOps.  Not sure why Visual Studio decided to create an html safe string when cloning from Azure DevOps Removing the %20 from the directory path resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 52):

In my case it was caused by a .NET Framework version mismatch.

One project was 3.5 and the other referencing project 4.6.1.

Comment: This also happens between 4.5.2 Vs. 4.6

Comment: Indeed, I had one of 4.6.1 and the rest was 4.5.2, thanks!

Comment: Yes, seems any time a framework version is different, this happens. Great error Microsoft!

Comment: Yup! I was trying to use a .Net 4.7.1 .dll when my project was .Net 4.6.1. The warning was hidden by other items, but no error about it. My error was a red herring

Comment: Indeed!, I add a project reference trying to use a .NET 4.7.1 and my project was .NET 4.6.1. It doesn't show me a error in the Error List Window, but in the console keeps telling me "The type or namespace name '...' does not exist in the namespace '...' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".
My solution was to move all the projects to .NET 4.8.

Answer (score 38):

**Visual Studio 2019** this worked for me:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete the hidden `.vs` folder
3. Reopen Visual Studio and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: This one worked

Comment: Using MAUI here, this did not directly fix the error but it helped. I had renamed a class without refactoring and one of my Views could not find it anymore. I could not see the relevant error in the Output log when I compiled. In order to see the right error in the Output log, I had to: 1. Close Visual Studio 2. Delete the `.vs` folder in the repo 3. Reopen Visual Studio and compile. This highlighted the view's unknown type reference error in the Output window (but it still didn't appear among the Errors)!

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 34):

Closing and reopening Visual Studio 2013 worked for me!

Comment: In my case, I also opened another project and then the original.

Answer (score 31):

Well, nothing in the previous answers worked for me, so it got me thinking about why am I clicking and hoping when as developers we should really try to understand what is going on here.

It seemed obvious to me that this incorrect meta data file reference must be held somewhere.

A quick search of the .csproj file showed the guilty lines. I had a section called <itemGroup> that seemed to be hanging onto the old incorrect filepath.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\MySiteOld\MySite.Entities\MySite.Entities.csproj">
        <Project>{5b0a347e-cd9a-4746-a3b6-99d6d010a6c2}</Project>
        <Name>Beeyp.Entities</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
...
```

So a simple fix really:

1. Backup your .csproj file.
2. Find the incorrect paths in the .csproj file and rename appropriately.

Please **make sure you backup your old .csproj before you fiddle**.

Comment: please MAKE SURE YOU USE VERSION CONTROL BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING

Answer (score 28):

In my case, it was an issue with my directory names.

If your solution path is something like `My Project%2c Very Popular%2c Unit Testing%2c Software and Hardware.zip`, it cannot resolve the metadata file, perhaps we should prevent some invalid words like `%2c`.

When a repository is cloned from certain sites, the directory name is URL encoded. Which would convert space characters in directory names to `%20`, forward slashes to `%2f`, underscores to `%5f`, etc. Although, I'm not sure why the `%` symbol is breaking things.

Renaming the path into one with valid characters resolved my issue. This can be done manually in the File Explorer. In my case, I just removed the `%2c`s.

Comment: that helped me, git extensions changed '.' to %20

Comment: @Gabriel Petersen, I agree with you. I had cloned a project from Git on AzureDevOps and it added %20 where there's spaces in a project directory name. So rename the directory and it should work.

Answer (score 26):

I also met this problem. Firstly you have to manually build you DLL project, by right-click, Build. Then it will work.

Comment: While this fix works, it doesn't actually fix the problem and could lead to more underlying problems. First of all, if you're working with code in a repository, it is bad form to require a new developer to jump through hoops to get the code to a point where it will build. Second of all, in order to see changes in the referenced project, you would have to manually rebuild it every time. Please see my answer for a more robust fix to the problem.

Comment: In my case, it does not even build the project individually, it gives me the same error. Let say my project name is "proj1", when I build it (manually as you said) it give me `Metadata file ...proj1.dll could not be found`!

Answer (score 17):

In my case, the problem was caused by a simple build error,

> error CS0067: The event 'XYZ' is never used

that, for any reason, did not show up in the error window.

Because of that, the Visual Studio build system seemed to miss the error and tried to build dependent projects, which in turn failed with the annoying metadata message.

The recommendation is -as stupid as it may sound-:

First look at your *Output Window*!

It took me half an hour before this idea hit me...

Comment: Exactly. I had a similar error. I found out it was related to an error in a dependant project that prevented a successful build.

Answer (score 14):

I got the same error "Metadata file '.dll' could not be found", and I tried several things described above, but the reason for the error was that I was referencing third-party DLL file which was targeting a .NET version higher that my project target .NET version. So the solution was to change the target framework of my project.

Comment: Well, I was about to answer the same, in my case I added a new project targeting .Net 4.5.x and It started to happen when, form that project I added a reference to a project that was using .Net 4.6.

Answer (score 12):

For me, it was trying to find a DLL in a path that used to contain the Project, but we'd moved it to a new directory. The Solution had the correct path to the Project, but Visual Studio somehow kept looking in the old location.

Solution: Rename each problem Project - just add a character or whatever - then rename it back to its original name.

This must reset some global cache of some kind in Visual Studio, because this clears both this issue up and several like it, while things like Clean do not.

Answer (score 12):

I added a new project to my solution and started getting this.

The reason? The project I brought in was targeting a different .NET framework (4.6 and my other two were 4.5.2).

Comment: I dont know why now but i was running my projects for a year like that. my sub project was 4.6.1 and main project was 4.5.2. it worked without any problem. suddenly i am getting this error but i dont want to downgrade the sub project because it has feature that exist in 4.6.1 i dont believe this is the problem. Microsoft explains it should still be working

Comment: TLDR: Check compile warnings. This is what happened to me but with a twist.  projs were at 4.5.2. Added new projects at 4.6. Installed nuget packages on 4.6 projects. Downgraded 4.6 projects to 4.5.2. Nugets were expecting 4.6. Downgrades of nugets solved.

Answer (score 11):

Coming back to this a few years later, this problem is more than likely related to the Windows maximum path limit:

*[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath)*, *[Maximum Path Length Limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath)*

Comment: Which is...? 260? Or slightly less (in practice)?

Comment: Not sure if this was the case. I tried top solution but that didn't work. I copied all code to parent folder to shorted the path (220 characters), reduced to 192 characters with it worked fine.
192 is longest path I can see in solution solution/obj/debug/net6.0/ref/ abc.xyz.dll

Answer (score 11):

It looks like such kind of errors related to the fact that Visual Studio doesn't provide correct information about an error. The developer doesn't even understand the reason for the failed build. It can be a syntax error or something else. In common, to solve such problems you should find the root of the problem (for example, look at the build log).

In my case the problem was in fact that the `Error List` window didn't show any errors. But really there were syntax errors; I found these errors in the `Output` window, and after fixing them, the problem was solved.

Comment: I experienced this problem as well. There was no error in the Error List, but the failed build results in DevOps showed the error

Answer (score 10):

For me it occurred when I included a new project to a solution.

Visual Studio automatically selects .NET framework 4.5.

I changed to version .NET 4.5.2 like the other libraries, and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

For me the following steps worked:

- Find the project that is not building
- Remove/add references to projects within the solution.

Comment: Right click on the reference "folder" in the solution explorer, "remove unused references". I did this on all my projects in this solution, it did the trick

Answer (score 9):

I was pulling my hair out with this problem also, but after trying the previous answers the only thing that worked for me was to open each project in my solution 1 by 1 and build them individually.

Then I closed Visual Studio 2013, reopened my solution and it compiled fine.

It's strange, because if I clicked each project in my Solution Explorer and tried to build them that way, they all failed. I had to open them alone in their own solutions.

Comment: Ugh, this. So many things Microsoft require a restart to work again.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a space in your solution name, this will also cause the issue. Removing the space from your solution name, so path doesn't contain %20 will solve this.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the issue was that I'd manually deleted a non-compilation file which was marked as "missing".  Once I deleted the reference to the now-missing file and recompiled - all was well.

Answer (score 8):

My instance of the problem was caused by a common project that had a duplicate class name in it (under a different filename). It is strange that Visual Studio could not detect that and instead just blew up the build process.

Comment: It is an additional solution to the same problem.  I know the OP is old, but based on the last couple of posts, people are still finding other causes.  Just trying to save the next guy some frustration as none of the other solutions worked for me either.

Answer (score 8):

I got this problem in Visual Studio 2012 in a solution that had many projects. Rebuilding each project in the solution manually in the same order as the Project Build Order (right-click and rebuild in Solution Explorer) fixed it for me.

Eventually I got to one that gave me a compile error. I fixed the error, and the solution would build correctly after that.

Comment: In my case, the error was hidden until I opened Visual Studio 2015 in Adminstrator mode. Only then did it show the compilation error. After fixing that, I could continue.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the methods explained here did not solved the problem for me.

> Finally, I fixed the problem by applying the following steps:

**1.** Close Visual Studio.

**2.** Delete all the contents in the bin folders of each project.

**3.** Open solution and rebuild.

Answer (score 6):

I too had the same error. It hides as in the below path.
The path which I referred to for the DLL file is like "D:\Assemblies Folder\Assembly1.dll".

But the original path in which the assembly referred was "D:\Assemblies%20Folder\Assembly1.dll".

Due to this path name variation, the assembly could not be retrieved from its original path and hence throws the "Metadata not found" error.

The solution is in Stack Overflow question *[How do I replace all the spaces with %20 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c)*.

Answer (score 6):

I'd faced the same problem. In my case I'd referenced to a class library project with higher **.Net version** than my project and VS failed to build the project and raised the same error you posted.

I simply set **.Net version** of my class library project(the one that had broken the build) identical to the .Net version of referenced project and problem solved.

Comment: Same problem, but on "Manage Packages for Solution" > Consolidate nothing was shown, I had to check the installed one by one. In my case: Microsoft.EntityFramework.*

Answer (score 6):

I hit and solved this problem today on VS2022 in a solution with a Blazor project.

The underlying problem is that I had introduced a routine C# compilation error
in C# code declared in a .razor file. VS2022 was dropping the display of the error from the Build Error List tab. I found the C# error by scanning the build output in the Output console log tab where my C# error was described as expected.

p.s. In case you are wondering, I had a Unit Test project referencing my Blazor web project. The project DLL reference from the Unit Test project to the Blazor app was complaining about the missing Blazor DLL.

Comment: Had the same problem after adding an additional parameter to a function which was called in a .razor-file. VS did not show me the error until I manually got into the razor-file and saw the red underlinings.

Comment: Same here, only using MAUI. However, I could not see the relevant error in the Output log. In order to see the right error in the Output log, I had to: 1. Close Visual Studio 2. Delete the `.vs` folder in the repo 3. Reopen Visual Studio and compile.

Comment: I had the same problem. A dublicated function in a partial class. Had to read the output to find the file in which the error was thrown.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the error message I don't believe the file path is being truncated. It looks to just be incorrect. If I'm reading the message correctly it appears to be looking for the DLL file at ...

> WORK=-\Tools\VersionManagementSystem\BusinessLogicLayer\bin\Debug\BusinessLogicLayer.dll

This is not a valid path. Is it possible that you have a macro definition in the build process set to an invalid value?

Comment: I dunno how as I haven't changed anything and don't have any custom build events or configurations

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue because `.nuget\NuGet.exe` was not included in my repository. Although I enabled `DownloadNuGetExe` in NuGet.targets, it reported a proxy error when trying to download it. This caused the rest of the project builds to fail.

Answer (score 4):

This error may be shown if you use fake assemblies. Removing fakes leads to successful build of the project.

Comment: What is a "fake assembly"? Can you elaborate? (Respond by expanding your answer.)

Answer (score 4):

I am running Visual Studio 2013.

It appears that the build dependencies were incorrect. Deleting the *.suo files did fix the problems I had.

Answer (score 4):

Just pointing out the blatantly obvious:  if you don't have "Show output window when build starts" enabled, make sure you're noticing if your build is failing (small "build failed" error in lower left)!!!!

Comment: I had something similar recently - out of the blue, hundreds of cs0006 errors in the Error log but nothing else (and I combed through it with a very fine comb). Eventually (!) I thought of looking at the Output window, and there was a compiler error reported, and sure enough in the code the error had a red squiggle under it. I have no idea why the error wasn't reported in the Errors window. VS2017 Enterprise.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error when I was trying to publish a web application. Turned out that one of a class properties was wrapped into

```
#if DEBUG
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
#endif
```

but the property usage was not. The publishing was done in Release configuration without the `DEBUG` symbol, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

For my case it was that I had commented out classes in a specific (empty) namespace:

```
namespace X.Y.Z.W
{

    // Class code

}
```

When I removed the namespace code and the import (using) commands of it - it fixed the problem.

In the build it was also saying - along with the missing DLL file of the project:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'W' does not exist in the namespace 'X.Y.Z' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4):

Removing the `packages` folder containing NuGet in the solution folder worked for me. After rebuilding everything worked again. Check `References` in the solution and check for references that have a yellow triangle.

Example picture:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case some of the projects in the solution were targeted to *Any CPU*, some of them to x86. The compilation error disappeared after unifying the platform target across the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had a class in 4.6.1 refering an interface that was in 4.6.2... upgrading the class to 462 fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in VS2019 .Net Core, ASP.Net Core solution.

1. Open a PowerShell console in the same location of the solution.
2. Type `dotnet restore` to restore al packages and projects
3. Type `dotnet build`. The solution will be built

Now it can be built also from Visual Studio IDE too. 
None of the other solution given worked for me

Answer (score 4):

For me it is still a "feature" in the current version of VS2022.

1. Building all ~80 projects of a solution
2. Cancelling the build in the middle
3. Unloading ~70 projects and doing a rebuild all

causes the error. Fix:

1. Reload all projects
2. Rebuild all up to the end
3. then do the unload

and a rebuild all succeeds without that metadata error

Answer (score 3):

I received this error after opening a project in which Entity Framework was referenced, so I deleted such references, and reinstalled Entity Framework version 6.0.0.0 through pthe acket manager this way:

```
install-package entityframework -version 6.0.0.0
```

The error was still showing, so I thought that those references were there because there was an older version of Entity Framework supposedly "preinstalled" on the project, but it was not really working.

So I went up to the file `packages.config` and noticed that there was another reference:

```
<packages>
  **<package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />**
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Then I deleted the line, cleaned and rebuild the project and the container solution, and it finally worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  In my case, the project would still build in release mode and it was just when I tried to build in debug that it failed.

What I ended up doing to fix the issue was simply copy all of the dlls (and other files from my release folder) into my debug folder.  After doing this for every project, the errors melted away.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when I decompiled a very old library, which was deployed in a production environment, but the source code was lost.

I took .dll, decompiled and generated projects and solution. I was unable to build the solution due to several errors of this kind.

Tips in previous answers did not help, but after a while I noticed missing references in some projects to several assemblies like System.dll.

Suppose there is project A dependent on project B. There was no reference to System.dll in project B, but the error after build was like "Metadata file 'B.dll' could not be found".

There was no error about missing System.dll in project B.

Adding reference on libraries like System.dll in project B solved the problem.
(System.Data, System.DirectoryServices, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, these errors were caused by some corruption in the NuGet package manager. Subprojects of the solution were not getting built, but no errors were showing because of the metadata errors.

Once all the NuGet packages were corrected, the project could build properly again.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had this error because, one of my project used a different .NET framework version from the others of the solution. I used the NuGet packages manager to install NLog, so, i think, it installed for the .Net version of this project.

I tried all solutions from this post, but none were working. I removed NLog, cleaned the solution and trid to compile: Same thing, CS006 error.

It was when I deleted all files in `obj\Debug` from this project that the solution compiled.

Answer (score 3):

My issue came when i wrote c# 7 code but the project was using older version for .net framework

Answer (score 3):

In VS 2019, under the project *References* check if there are any unresolved items by expanding ***Analyzers***:

[image]

For me, there were two `.dll` files with wrong paths. Right click on each and select *Remove*:

[image]

Build the project, then build the solution. 
Done.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem may be that you have mixed adding references to DLL files and projects in the solution.

If you have projects A, B, and C:

- A references B and C as projects in the solution.
- B references C as a DLL file (reference to a file)

You can build each project separately, but you can't rebuild a solution ending with: Metadata file 'C.dll' could not be found.

Changing the reference from a file to a project in the solution helps.

Comment: It's funny how this shows up as Page 2 solution to this problem but in my case this was the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal case, I had failed to add a reference to one of the projects in the solution and this is what was kicking up the error for me.

Answer (score 2):

aaaaaand six years later during an upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 the same problem. Because this particular solution is not in this list I'm adding to it.

Two referenced dll's were in the c:\windows\system32... folder.
Moving them to a non system folder and adding a reference to the new folder fixed it finally. The rest of the issues was indeed what others have said here already

Comment: Just had the same problem with one of the projects in my solution. Unchecking and checking "build" didn't work. What did the trick for me was to remove the project from the solution and add it again.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Unload and Reload on the project did it for me. After trying a bunch of the answers here. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) being dumb and, even though my project targets C# 6 I was being offered refactorings to use C# 7-only features.

For this reason I ended up changing this code,

```
private DateTime? _joinedDate;
[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
public DateTime JoinedDate
{
    get { return _joinedDate ?? DateTime.Now; }
    set { _joinedDate = value; }
}
```

into this code:

```
private DateTime? _joinedDate;
[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
public DateTime JoinedDate
{
    get => _joinedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
    set => _joinedDate = value;
}
```

For some reason having the getter and setter using expression bodies made the compiler come up with that metadata error instead of a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem. In my case multiple C# projects were referenced as DLL files. Any compile time error in a project which is used as a DLL file (in other projects) would result in a flood of errors. The reason is, the compile time error prevents the creation of the corresponding DLL file, and this results in a series of errors in projects which refer to the missing DLL file.

Therefore when you rebuild in Solution Explorer (ignoring the trivial compile time errors), a bunch of "metadata file .dll could not be found" errors will occur (making you think what wrong you did other than a simple rebuild).

If you are facing this problem, then the best solution is to clean the solution and then build each project one by one to figure out which project is initiating the error.

Answer (score 2):

As user @burzhuy points out, it can be important to look at the `Output`window, and not just the `Error List` window.

In my case I was working on making modifications to the [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform) compiler. Its build projects run an extra check to see if the public fields are consistent with what has been defined as the compiler's public interface, otherwise it produces an RS0016 or RS0017 error. I had added a couple of public fields, and fixed the RS0016 error by hovering the mouse over the error and selecting "Add to public API".

Later I changed my mind and moved the public fields to a different class. For some reason this produced the "Metadata file could not be found error", and the more I fiddled with it the more errors I got.

You need to to find the correct `PublicAPI.Unshipped.txt`file (in my case it was in `E:\Roslyn\32414\src\Compilers\Core\Portable`) and edit it manually to remove the lines that are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and another solution.

The issue:
One solution, multiple Projects. The main application that uses some of the other results failed, saying:

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Repos\TheApplication\TheApplicationCommon\bin\Debug\TheApplication.dll' could not be found

But actually this Project generated `C:\Repos\TheApplication\TheApplicationCommon\bin\Debug\TheApplicationCommon.dll`
Another project that also uses the same dll compiled flawlessly.

Before I updated an internal NuGet-package that used PostSharp 3.x.x.x and now uses PostSharp 4.x.x.x. And my solution was to add this to my *.csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="...">
  <Import Project="..." Condition="..." />
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <AssemblyName>TheApplication</AssemblyName>
    ...
    <SkipPostSharp>True</SkipPostSharp> <!-- This line -->
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

Another Solution->Clean, another Solution->Rebuild and it works locally and on the build server.

Hope it helps someone. The thread is old and quite long but this issue returns often and I didn't see this solution yet. Btw using Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.x).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved this problem after noticing that I had referenced a .Net Framework 4.7 project as a dependency on a .Net Framework 4.6.1 project. After migrating project 4.7 to 4.6.1 my application compiled normally

Comment: This was the issue i had as well, the error was being swallowed when building from the project containing the other projects.  Opening the new or suspect projects and trying to compile revealed the mismatch in target framework (not as an error but in the output log).

Answer (score 2):

I have agree all aboves just a difference.
In my case: I am using Visual Studio 2019. I closed VS-2019 and opened with VS-2017. and rebuild the project everything working great!
For whom in my position date is: 4/19/2019

Comment: For me, there was an error in code. But, VS2019 was not showing where error is - instead, it was just showing 'metadata could not be found...' - because it was not able to build project. After restart, all was good - error was shown, I've made correction and solution was normally build. Sometimes restart makes miracles with Microsoft products.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the parent folder of the solution had a `%20` in the name. I renamed the parent folder by removing the `%20` and the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2019:

- Close Visual Studio.
- Delete the .vsccc file that lives in the same
  folder as your solution file.
- Open the solution and rebuild.

Comment: No files of that sort are in the same folder as my solution file.

Answer (score 2):

I'd faced the same problem. First i cleared all nuget cache from tools>Nuget Package Manager>Package Manager settings  then click "Clear All Nuget Cache(s)". After this opened Powershell and run "dotnet restore"  then "dotnet build". In my case this solution fixed my errors.

Comment: I just had to run `dotnet restore xxx.sln` from a dev prompt due to nuget restore commad not picking up PackageReferences

Answer (score 2):

Working with a Blazor WebAssembly ASP.NET Core hosted app, this problem arose when I deleted the WeatherForecast model and this caused a build error that wasn't visible as an error.

If this is the case for you, just remove the FetchData.razor file, and you'll be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

**Check that the project does not contain errors, otherwise the DLL cannot be generated**

In my case, I had syntactic errors that were not visible from the Error List,
when I checked the Output tab line by line I found some errors in the **cshtml classes**

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the solution and click Clean.
2. Right click on the solution and click Rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that if you remove Microsoft.CSharp assembly as a reference in the project, you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check the .csproj file of main project. Visual Studio does not clean that up in case you remove projects or alter references in the solution.

I had old projects referenced three times in the .csproj file and compile showed this error to those removed projects.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, it seems like this error can come from everywhere.

Anyway, I added a new WebAPI controller to my MVC application and it automagically got all the references from NuGet. Little bit later I removed the references from the NuGet UI, but I forgot to delete the files using them (i.e. `System.Http`).

For some reason, the error I was receiving was this, along with a simple warning about a variable not being used.

I commented out the variable to get rid at least of the warning and rebuilding pointed me out of all the files that were using the non-existing reference. After deleting those files, everything went OK.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error with Visual Studio 2015 when I removed the type annotation from a call to an extension method, which left only the empty angle brackets behind.

So instead of `obj.extensionMethod<Type>()` I had `obj.extensionMethod<>()`.

I would classify this as a bug in Visual Studio since I don't see how that mistake could produce that error.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous solutions worked for me so I'll share what did.

I had this problem after merging some new class libraries from another branch which referred to each other. Deleting the references in the projects and recreating them finally fixed the problem. Apparently Visual Studio had merged over the wrong file paths.

Answer (score 1):

This issue could occur due to a syntax error in your code that might not be visible to you because of the Meta Data error. So review your source file before doing any of the actions in previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I had two Visual Studio windows opened, my project was running in debug in one window, and I tried to build it in another.

I had to stop debugging and then it let me build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error message for the simple reason that, after getting the latest version of the project from TFS, the wrong project in the solution was marked as the startup project. Choosing the correct project as the startup project solved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in VS2019. Here is what you need to do:

1. Push latest changes on some branch
2. Delete the project
3. Remove project from QuickStart - you can try to reference not existing project and it will ask you to remove
4. Clone the project
5. Run the project

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem. In my case I delete all bin and obj folders from all projects then this error will resolve for me. Try this for one more try to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when tried to **publish** my project,

All answered above, not helped me...

I just change my deploy and the **publish** successed!

Answer (score 1):

I had an quite unusual case of this error, but maybe someone would benefit from it.

I had this error with missing .dll file of one of projects in solution (with target framework netstandard 2.0) I'm working on and at once error with reference (to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) this project uses.

This solution was cloned from git repository, and same solution compiled well for other people in my team.

I tried every propsed solution for issue - restarting VS, computer; cleaning project; checking and unchecking build checkboxes; checking if build order is proper etc.

**I figured out that manifest of this project was not selected by default (dropdown of manifest in project properties was empty and disabled). Therefore I tried to add it, but nothing worked.**

At last I started comparing this **project .csproj file** with one in other, older version of this project, which compiled without problem.
After a bit of usless tries **I figured out, that path to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word is the same in both projects, even thought it was a relative path starting with lots of "go up" symbols ( ..\ ). And not working project was one level lower than other.**

**Adding one more "go up" symbol ( ..\ ) in reference path to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word inside project .csproj file solved the issue.**

I have no idea why this path was created that way and doesn't update in my case, while it work properly for others in my team.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was an unused import "using ApsNetCore" on a Controller. Removed it, clean, rebuild it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

in my case: go to add references. in reference manager window uncheck dll project for other projects. save it. again add reference dll project to other projects.

Answer (score 1):

**VS2022:** Cause not found in the extensive listing already here.

Had a static class comprised entirely of static methods.  Removing static from the class declaration didn't raise either a compile error or warning but did cause the OP build error.

Reverted the class declaration back to static and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a local project is automatically referenced twice.
Check your .csproj file for something like this and **remove one line**:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ReferenceProject\ReferenceProject.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ReferenceProject\ReferenceProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange! I tried all the previous answers and unfortunately nothing worked in my case.

I encountered two errors:

1. Missing .dll file
2. Method already defined at another place with the same parameters

I have cleared the second error first by removing the function which has been duplicated at another place.

My first error - that is .dll file missing has solved it on its own.

I want to say, if you have more than a single error along with the .dll missing file error, please try to solve the other errors first. Maybe the .dll error solves it on its own!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after `getting latest` (Team Foundation Server (TFS) command).

After resolving the conflicts I found using a statement for a `namespace that does not exist in the project`.

So I removed that `using` statement then `clean and rebuild`, and everything was OK.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this problem after changing the solution a lot, shelving the changes and undoing it.

Only way to solve it was removing and adding again the mapping from TFS to my local folder.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error because I had the following line in my code (looks like I was still thinking in SQL mode):

```
if(myVar is null)
    DoSomething();
```

Visual studio (2017) reported no errors at design or compile time however the project would not build and gave the "missing .dll" error.  Upon changing the erroneous line to:

```
if(myVar == null)
```

The problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

None of the dozens of answers so far worked for me. In my case, I also got the error:

> Tuple element name 'Value' is inferred. Please use language version 7.1 or greater to access an element by its inferred name

This appeared next to "Metadata file '.dll' could not be found" errors on building, but it disappeared shortly after, as errors sometimes do as the IDE "catches up".

Double clicking on the error to find it, and removing the offending code, fixes it.

Otherwise, you can, try this in Visual Studio:

Menu *Project* → <Project name> *Properties* → *Build* → button *Advanced* → *Language Version* → *C#* <latest minor version> (e.g. "C# 5.0")

And that fixes it too.

It looks like "Metadata file '.dll' could not be found" is often a symptom of some other underlying problems, so if none of the top solutions work for you, check other errors and warnings and try to find the real issue.

Comment: Can you provide another example of the value of "Language Version"?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the target framework solved the problem:

1. Right click on the project and select *Properties*
2. In *Application*, change *Target framework* to the same as the main project (e.g. ".NET Framework 4.5").

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a bunch of other build errors as well (some simple type conversions) along with this one, I was scratching my head trying to solve this, and I wasn't focusing on the other errors.

What finally solved my problem was that I fixed all the other build error and then I build again and it build successfully.

So in case you have other build errors along with missing DLL file error, and nothing else is working for you then try to fix the other errors first and then build the solution again.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was an error that didn't come up in the build output, namely I had two utility classes that were in different namespaces initially. I changed the namespace of the second one to match the first one's (without knowing there was another one utility class in the first one), and that's when this error started to come up.

I imagine the build output error surfaced, because the Logic Layer library DLL file could not be built, and the main application couldn't find it.

The solution was to change back the second utility class to a different namespace and that's when the real build errors started to pour in. After sorting them out the build went through just fine.

As an overview, if any of the previous solutions doesn't work for you, you might have suppressed errors in the code that Visual Studio is not showing, so try to retrack your coding steps and check for any irregularities.

PS: This was in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio IDE doesn't do any building behind the scenes, the Msbuild application does.  The VS IDE essentially just constructs the project file that is used by Msbuild and quite often it makes mistakes if you leave it up to the IDE to figure things out on it's own.  If you are getting the `Metadata file '.dll' could not be found` error it is likely due to the fact that the correct/expected assemblies are not being found.  So perhaps Visual Studio might be creating a project file for a 4.5 framework app, and expecting 4,5 assemblies, while you are referencing 4.0 assemblies.  So look at your Visual Studio settings for incompatibilities or go into the project file yourself, and manually fix it by specifying the correct path `<Reference Include="C:\\correct path to assembly\\yourAssembly.dll" />`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case inside my `Web.config` file changing this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

to this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

When I did a build, it would usually show errors like this in Visual Studio 2017:

```
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\src\ProjectDir\MyApp\bin\x64\Debug\Inspection.exe' could not be found MyApp   C:\src\ProjectDir\MyApp\CSC 1   Active
```

But sometimes an error like this would show for a couple seconds and then it would disappear and switch back to the above message:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MyApp.Model.Entities.Asset' to 'MyApp.Model.Model.Entities.Inspection' MyApp   C:\src\ProjectDir\MyApp\ViewModels\AssetDetailsViewModel.cs 1453    Active
```

So I spent time troubleshooting the first error but the real problem turned out to be due to the second error.  First I had to delete all the /bin and /obj directories, then I also deleted the .suo files as indicated above.  This allowed me to narrow down the problem to an interface issue.

In my interface I had this:

```
    Task<IList<Defect>> LoadDefects(Asset asset);
```

But in my actual implementation I had this code:

```
    public virtual async Task<IList<Defect>> LoadDefects(Inspection inspection)
    {
       var results ...
       // ....

        return results;
    }
```

The build completed successfully after I updated the interface to this:

```
    Task<IList<Defect>> LoadDefects(Inspection inspection);
```

So it seems like caching in VS caused it to keep showing the CS0006 error when the actual problem was the CS1503 error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened to me when I was referencing NuGet packages locally and moved their directory to somewhere else, I changed the path inside `NuGet.Config` but unfortunately I discovered that I should change the `.csproject` files manually to update the reference path, but the error message `CS0006` was way far from describing this problem.
Generally it also happens when there is a reference to DLL that couldn't be found, to be able to identify issue search your references in the project with the problem you will find some references with warning icon associated with them, try fixing those and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these answers sound like trial and error. In my case though, it was simple: the referenced dll was not found in that particular location.

If you see the build errors, typically in this case, the build complains about many dlls. The key is to find the right dll that is missing. In my case, one of the projects in my solution had a direct dll reference instead of a project reference. So, I needed to build the project that outputs that dll before building the failing solution to make sure the failing solution finds the missing dll in that particular location.

Wow.. that was simple, but quite difficult to put it into words.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen because you are using features that are not supported by the version of **.net** selected for the project.

In my case the reason was I used **??** operator to check for null and throw exception.

Strange enough that **VS** doesn't inform about the actual reason of the problem in the list of build errors.

But you can find this information in the **Output** logs of the build.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the bin/obj folders and then rebuilding the project worked for me.

In my case, what I believe happened was that I experienced a run time error the first time I built the project so my dll file was not not generated.

This happened when referencing a project from another. The project I was referencing was the one with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after updating the dlls/nuget.

I could solve this manually by correcting the .csproj file. Mostly the version wasn't updated in the file. 
For example :

```
<Analyzer> Include="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.**VersionCheckAnalyzer.2.9.1**\analyzers\dotnet\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.dll"/>

<Analyzer> Include="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.**VersionCheckAnalyzer.2.9.7**\analyzers\dotnet\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.dll"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that the dependor project (the project depending upon the one in the error message) was missing values in its "Assembly version" fields under the project's "Properties → Application → Assembly Information...".  I just added in the same numbers which were there for "File version", clicked "OK" and the compiler errors disappeared!

[image: Missing Assembly Version]

It turns out that re-adding the `AssemblyVersion` then building the project again resulted in another error claiming that it was already present in the project.  It was!  Under the properties node of the project in Solution Explorer, there was a "SolutionVersionInfo.cs" file which also contained an `AssemblyVersion` attribute - deleting this file from the project resolved this error.

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem occurred because I was in-lining variable.

so the following does successful build:

```
ReportCategory reportCategoryEnum;
Enum.TryParse(reportCategory, true, out reportCategoryEnum);
```

while when I modified my code as following, no errors were shown but build was failing

```
Enum.TryParse(reportCategory, true, out ReportCategory reportCategoryEnum);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted the git folder and removed Git (Azure DevOps).
This was the only method that I did that worked.

I tried clean, rebuild, reconfigure build, deleting bin and obj folders; nothing worked.
When I removed solution of Git, voilá! It worked for me.

I don't understand, but this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a merge conflict in one .csproj file and ended up with two copies of one build target.

`<Compile Include="SystemCodes\APSystemCodes.cs" />`

After I eliminated the duplicate the build worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was wrong folder name. If you close from source that replaces spaces with '%20', you will get such errors.
Solution - just rename badly named folders.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Solution's Folder Explorer and delete the unused project folder that was throwing error. In my case, after deleting the project, the folder was still present in the directory. After deleting the folder solution built successfully!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using Visual Studio 2019.
After a closer look on what was going on in the background i found out there were errors on appended class libraries which in turn were not compiling correctly and throughing at the same time the error "Meta data file not found". Corrected the errors, compiled it again and all worked.

In my case the answer was found on analysis of the output tab.

Answer (score 0):

The framework version of the current project differs from remaining projects.
Change of framework version to existing projects version will resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing else here worked for me, but this did:

1. Stash changes with Git
2. Clean and build
3. Apply stash
4. Rebuild

Now, suddenly VS pointed me to an error that wasn't showing up before. Furthermore, there were several errors in that one file that intellisense was ignoring. I corrected those without the help of red underlines and then was able to successfully build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS 2019. Our group is supposed to upgrade from 2017 to 2019.

### Actual solution

I tried to clone to a folder on my C: drive that was part of my roaming profile (so on the network). I created a local folder that was guaranteed to be untracked and cloned there instead. The issues went away.

Notes:

- This could not have been a path-length issue because I also tried cloning it into a folder with a name longer than the original path, and it built fine.
- This could not have been due to spaces in the file name because our solution folders have spaces in them.
- This issue seems to only affect VS2019 and not VS2017. Though we have run into roaming profile issues before, it used to happen when we tried to sync with Git, not build.

### Other things I tried/checked to no avail

- Restart VS, logout, restart, etc.
- Delete solution and re-clone from DevOps repo
- No Build Errors in our code
- Uncheck and re-check Build Configuration boxes
- Build-order makes sense
- All .NET Framework Targets the same. (In my case 4.6. Probably doesn't matter.)
- DLLs actually exist in path
- Reload project
- Reinstall NuGet Packages
- Re-add DLLs

Answer (score 0):

## Case Sensitive

In my case the error message was as follows

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe"  /i "C:\Users\cmaggiul\source\repos\consume-evalue-api\EValueApi\EValueApi\bin\debug\EValueApi.dll"" exited with code 3.  EValueApi

I followed the path to the **EValueApi.dll** file and realized that the debug directory was capitalized in Windows.  I changed the directory to be lower case ( to match the location being used by gacutil.exe and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a reference to another project which I deleted but I never used it in the code and therefore I didn't get any compilation errors.

Tip: Check if you have any references to other projects in your solution which do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with my project, I added console application in a solution but those other solution was not working and showing .dll not found, so I tried this method:

1. Right click on the project which is having issue
2. Click on Application tab, that is default
3. Change output type Console Application to Class Library

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when doing a clean CLI rebuild of a MonoGame solution that had pure content projects.

The solution was to add a single dummy class file with an empty constructor to each of the content projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I mistakenly wrote `#endregion` twice. The problem was solved when I deleted one.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be caused by the fact that you have multiple projects in your solution but different projects target different versions of .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that someone had copied the source project into the project, added a project reference to debug an issue and then re-added the NuGet package without removing the project reference!

This actuall built on some dev machines and failed on others, depending on if it tried to use the NuGet package or the project.

Manually editing the project files to delete the project references resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me I checked the warnings not errors and noticed something wrong with one .dll in a bin folder.

I deleted that bin folder, Clean solution, Rebuild, all works now.