# How do I replace all the spaces with %20 in C#?

Tags: c#, url, urlencode

I want to make a string into a URL using C#. There must be something in the .NET framework that should help, right?

Comment: This question title does not match the question. To replace all spaces with %20 (the title) in C# you could use `String.Replace(" ", "%20")`. If you are building an URL all you need to do is put an URL value in a string: `string url = "https://site/app/?q=cats"` But if OP was talking about passing an URL as a GET parameter as part of another URL that is something else entirely, which itself different from, say, emitting an URL into an HTML anchor tag in ASP.NET (or whatever).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx).

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string url)
```

Comment: I think [Uri.EscapeUriString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the appropriate method if we have to be religious about it :)

Comment: @StoyanDimov: `EscapeUriString()` doesn't escape `&` nor `=` nor `?`, so `EscapeDataString()` does appear to be the one to use.

Comment: Someone had edited this question to completely change the answer. We [should not use editing to change the meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) of a particular post.

Comment: @palswim Yes, but the "accepted" answer can't be the one you reverted to: `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` encodes space as `+` and not `%20`, so this one is totally incorrect.

Comment: @palswim I reverted my rollback: The accepted answer *was* indeed the ***incorrect*** one. Go figure.

Comment: Mine is adding `+` instead of %20... any idea why?

Comment: Wrong answer - Don't use `UrlEncode` because it replaces spaces with `+` (instead of `%20` which the OP was specifically asking for) which is not a standard URI scheme. `decodeURI` and `decodeURIComponent` in JavaScript will not decode this properly. Use `Uri.EscapeDataString` which can be decoded properly by JavaScript for good round-trip usage of encoded data and URIs

Comment: `which is not a standard URI scheme` < actually it is: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

Answer (score 130):

Another way of doing this is using     [`Uri.EscapeUriString(stringToEscape)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, this method doesn't escape `&` characters.

Comment: It also doesn't escape `=`, nor `?`. It appears `Uri.EscapeDataString()` is the way to go.

Comment: It doesn't escape `#` either

Answer (score 51):

I found useful `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(string str);`

It replaces spaces with %20 and not with +.

Comment: There is, at least in 4.0.
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("a%20b") yields "a b"

Comment: It works but don't use this since it is for browsers. Use Uri.EscapeUriString(STRING) instead. MSDN : "Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use UrlEncode." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlpathencode.aspx

Comment: I found it helpful because I just wanted to encode part of the URL but still have it clickable. These did more than desired: System.Uri.EscapeDataString(url) and HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(url)

Comment: I needed to encode spaces to %20 and not to + in order to successfully post to Twitter.  UrlEncode(url) turns spaces into + and therefore was not the correct answer for my problem.

Answer (score 27):

To properly escape spaces as well as the rest of the special characters, use [`System.Uri.EscapeDataString(string stringToEscape)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx).

Comment: If a [comment is an actual answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp/36462468#comment3483210_1517592), somebody needs to make that an answer for the question.

Comment: yes, this one handles space, # and %, but encode / to %2f

Answer (score 19):

As commented on the approved story, the [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) method replaces spaces with + instead of %20.
Use one of these two methods instead: [Uri.EscapeUriString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Uri.EscapeDataString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Sample code:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://mywebsite.com/api/get me this file.jpg")
//Output: "https%3a%2f%2fmywebsite.com%2fapi%2fget+me+this+file.jpg"

Uri.EscapeUriString("https://mywebsite.com/api/get me this file.jpg");
//Output: "https://mywebsite.com/api/get%20me%20this%20file.jpg"
Uri.EscapeDataString("https://mywebsite.com/api/get me this file.jpg");
//Output: "https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Fapi%2Fget%20me%20this%20file.jpg"

//When your url has a query string:
Uri.EscapeUriString("https://mywebsite.com/api/get?id=123&name=get me this file.jpg");
//Output: "https://mywebsite.com/api/get?id=123&name=get%20me%20this%20file.jpg"
Uri.EscapeDataString("https://mywebsite.com/api/get?id=123&name=get me this file.jpg");    
//Output: "https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Fapi%2Fget%3Fid%3D123%26name%3Dget%20me%20this%20file.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do this too, found this question from years ago but question title and text don't quite match up, and using `Uri.EscapeDataString` or `UrlEncode` (don't use that one please!) doesn't usually make sense unless we are talking about passing URLs as parameters to other URLs.

(For example, passing a callback URL when doing open ID authentication, Azure AD, etc.)

Hoping this is more pragmatic answer to the question: *I want to make a string into a URL using C#, there must be something in the .NET framework that should help, right?*

**Yes** - two functions are helpful for making URL strings in C#

- `String.Format` for formatting the URL
- `Uri.EscapeDataString` for escaping any parameters in the URL

This code

```
String.Format("https://site/app/?q={0}&redirectUrl={1}", 
  Uri.EscapeDataString("search for cats"), 
  Uri.EscapeDataString("https://mysite/myapp/?state=from idp"))
```

produces this result

`https://site/app/?q=search%20for%20cats&redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite%2Fmyapp`

Which can be safely copied and pasted into a browser's address bar, or the `src` attribute of a HTML `A` tag, or used with `curl`, or encoded into a QR code, etc.

Comment: And JavaScript equivalent would be something like `"https://site/app/?q=" + encodeURIComponent("search for cats") + "&redirectUrl=" + encodeURIComponent("https://mysite/myapp/?state=from idp")` which produces the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

HttpUtility.UrlDecode works for me:

```
var str = "name=John%20Doe";
var str2 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str);
```

str2 = "name=John Doe"

Answer (score -2):

[HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

The below code will replace repeating space with a single %20 character.

Example:

Input is:

```
Code by Hitesh             Jain
```

Output:

```
Code%20by%20Hitesh%20Jain
```

#### Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    string replacedStr = null;

    // This loop will repalce all repeat black space in single space
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (!(Convert.ToString(str[i]) == " " &&
            Convert.ToString(str[i + 1]) == " "))
        {
            replacedStr = replacedStr + str[i];
        }
    }
    replacedStr = replacedStr + str[str.Length-1]; // Append last character
    replacedStr = replacedStr.Replace(" ", "%20");
    Console.WriteLine(replacedStr);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

[HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)

From the documentation:

```
String TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
String EncodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```

But this actually encodes HTML, not URLs. Instead use *UrlEncode(TestString)*.

Comment: The OP is asking about URL Encoding; not HTML Encoding.

Comment: No, this is for HTML encoding, not URL encoding (as the name implies...)

Comment: Yup, you're right, use UrlEncode() for encoding urls - this is for encoding Html Entities only