# URL Encoding in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I replace all the spaces with %20 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp)

I'm looking for a url encoding method in C#. I know Server.UrlEncode but I think that encodes spaces as a + symbol. I think I remember one that does spaces as %20 but cannot remember what it is. Does any one know or am I getting this confused with something else?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp

Comment: Excellent Uri.EscapeDataString was what I was looking for. Thanks @dotoree

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode Method (String)...URL-encodes a string and returns the encoded string.

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string url)
```