# URL encode in C#

Tags: c#, urlencode

I'm having trouble finding the correct way to URL encode a string in C#. What I want is to encode the string `some string` to `some%20code`. Using `HttpUtility.URLEncode();` method encode is to `some+string`.

Comment: This *is* the correct way though.

Comment: So what is the problem? you should use HttpUtility.URLEncode

Comment: So, is there something wrong with `string.Replace("+", "%20")`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) does the right thing here.

> Encodes a URL string. The UrlEncode method can be used to encode the entire URL, including query-string values.

When it comes to spaces on the URL, a `+` or `%20` are both correct.

Also see [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634271/1583).

Comment: The problem was that I was sending a HTTP request to get the web page, where '+' was not valid. Eg. Sending a query with 'some+string' would search for 'some+string', not 'some string'.

Comment: What is the minimum required .NET version for HttpUtility.UrlEncode() (not necessarily what is listed in the MSDN page)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want spaces encoded as `%20` instead of `+`, you have to do the encoding yourself.

In URL encoding a `+` means space. You can also use `%20`, just as you can use the character code variant for any character, but the built in encoding uses the shorter variant.

Answer (score 0):

This thread includes a discussion of some of the in-built encoding options for URIs:

[How do I replace all the spaces with %20 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp)