# Encode string URL without using HttpServerUtility

Tags: c#, url, encoding

I have a Sandbox solution webpart<sup>1</sup> that receives a absolute URL in the webpart settings's section.

Due to native limitations of sandboxes solutions, I'm looking for a `C# - code` for **encode an absolute URL without using HttpServerUtility and related/pre-built classes.**

I already search and try the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236038/4092887) and also this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784454/url-encode-in-c-sharp#comment14025795_10784454), but I can't understand or get a more legible code or approach for create a more sutile for my specific situation.

---

<sup>1</sup> *I'm working on a sandboxed solution that I was developed a few months ago and change sandboxed solution to Apps/Add-ins is not valid in this case.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239567/decode-escaped-url-without-using-httputility-urldecode

Comment: @MethodMan thank you very much. if you want to create an answer, you can and I'll accept if **(for the points that you can get)**.

Comment: I will post a working example based off of this posts URL and you can see the output below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var urlAbsoluteSample = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075880/encode-string-url-without-using-httpserverutility?noredirect=1#comment55905829_34075880";
var labelText = "Encoded absolute URL: " + Uri.EscapeDataString(urlAbsoluteSample);
```

> Encoded absolute URL: http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F34075880%2Fencode-string-url-without-using-httpserverutility%3Fnoredirect%3D1%23comment55905829_34075880

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@MethodMan's comment which lined to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075880/encode-string-url-without-using-httpserverutility#comment55905503_34075880), it wasn't need build C# custom code for this purpose.

You can use [the static method Uri.UnescapeDataString() to decode your URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/239695).

Here is the full answer:

```
String urlAbsoluteSample = "http://..."; // use any absolute URL for your purpose.
Label1.Text = "Encoded absolute URL: " + Uri.EscapeDataString(urlsFeeds[0]);
```