# Uri.EscapeUriString for a query

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to trying to get this query to work:

```
  HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("&query=select * from person limit1")
  as HttpWebRequest;
```

but what i need to do for that is put %20 for ever space like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create( 
"&query=select%20*%20from%20person%20limit%201") 
as HttpWebRequest;
```

but i want to do that automaticly and read that  Uri.EscapeUriString was the best way to do that but i don't know how to implement that.

I hope you guys can help.

Comment: so are you trying to replace spaces with `%20` ?

Comment: Be very careful when accepting raw sql as part of a query string - you are supremely vulnerable to SQL Injection (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). EscapeUriString is a static method on the URI class. However, I believe your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?:

```
WebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString("&query=select * from person limit1"))
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Derp... still tnx tough