# Convert from %20 to normal character (replace)

Tags: c#

I've searched for this and cannot find any hint anywhere.

Basically there is a program that formats their file name like this

hello%20world%28hello%20world%29

which is supposed to mean hello world(hello world)

now im wondering is there any way that I could read every file name and anything that uses "%ascii" would be converted to normal text (e.g above).

Thanks in advance guys. I'm not that experienced in code and I'm hoping that someone could help me.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Use [`System.Uri.UnescapeDataString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx):

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("hello%20world%28hello%20world%29");
```

Prints:

```
hello world(hello world)
```