# stop %20 replacing spaces from the URL string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to display a URL in my sharepoint list programmatically and the filename has some spaces , so by default it is taking %20 . how can i stop this behaviour , how can i show original filename with the spaces .

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can follow @inquisitive_mind's link ... except it seems like you want the opposite of that answer (you want `UrlDecode` instead if you're displaying a URL in a list).

Comment: yes i did that but it is showing page not found error . so i want the exact filename with the spaces

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i tried that UrlDecode , but the problem is that in my code when i checked for if(string.contains(%20)) {string.urldecode} it doesnt work because there is no %20 , it is getting generated at the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Net;
```

You can decode it as below:

```
string yourFileNameinURL = "My%20Name";
string yourFileNameYouWant = WebUtility.UrlDecode(yourFileNameinURL);
Console.WriteLine(yourFileNameYouWant);
```