# put a link with spaces in href property

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
string testURL = 'www.google.com/just test'

StringBuilder emailBody = new StringBuilder();

 emailBody.Append("<tr>");
 emailBody.Append("<td> Just the URL </td>");
 emailBody.Append("<td> String with href property </td>");
 emailBody.Append("</tr>");
 emailBody.Append("<tr>");
 emailBody.Append("<td>" + testURL + "</td>"); // it displays: www.google.com/just test
 emailBody.Append("<td> <a href=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(testURL) + ">" + name + "</a> </td>"); 
 // the href property displays only: www.google.com/just
 emailBody.Append("</tr>");
```

How can I achieve this? I tried with Uri.EscapeDataString() method

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp

Comment: Also, the code as you wrote it won't compile. You're missing a `+` between `href=" Uri.EscapeDataString`, and your testURL string literal should be surrounded by `"` instead of `'`

Comment: Ohhh. My fault. That's happening when you see the accepted answer, but though you take into consideration the most voted comment. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, don't delete it, flag it as a duplicate

Comment: Also, when I run the code you have, (with those 2 fixes), I get `<tr><td> Just the URL </td><td> String with href property </td></tr><tr><td>www
google.com/just test</td><td> <a href=www.google.com%2Fjust%20test> </a> </td> ` so there doesn't seem to be a mistake here? (ow, except that you're missing `"` in the href itself)

Comment: could you try my answer, and see if it works that way? (seems to be more of a malformed HTML issue than a C# issue)

Answer (score 1):

href should be in the form `href="something"`not `href=something`
 so replace

```
emailBody.Append("<td> <a href=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(testURL) + ">" + name + "</a> </td>");
```

with

```
emailBody.Append("<td> <a href=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(testURL) + "\">" + name + " </a> </td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(testURL)
```

Comment: Then it returns "", I tried

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string testURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces with %20 in testURL.