# C# ASP.NET How to Request.QueryString[""] with spaces or &

Tags: c#, asp.net

Needed help again

So I have this code

```
<a href="/Categories.aspx?categoryName=Electronics & Gadgets" class="clearfix">
```

How to make sure that the requestString will retrieve everything from "Electronics & Gadgets" and not just "Electronics"?

Thank you

Comment: You need to url encode the value "Electronics & Gadgets"

Comment: See [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You should write something like

```
<a href="<%= "/Categories.aspx?categoryName=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Electronics & Gadgets") %>" class="clearfix">Link</a>
```

as the query string value is not a valid url format.

In this case,

> the space " " and ampersand "&" characters will be encoded to "+" and "%26" respectively.

** Note that the ampersand character was used to concatenate multiple query strings so it must be properly encoded.

Threfore the url formatted link would be

> /Categories.aspx?categoryName=Electronics+%26+Gadgets

You'll then use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to parse the query string value in your code behind.

---

References:-

[MSDN HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx)