# Convert string to URL in c#

Tags: c#, string, url

It definitely has been asked many times, but offered solutions does not seem to work.

Input:

```
sample text
```

Output:

```
sample%20text
```

I'm using suggested `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` but instead of desired output it returns:

```
sample+text
```

Am i doing something wrong, or this method is no longer valid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace all the spaces with %20 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586/how-do-i-replace-all-the-spaces-with-20-in-c) Here is [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20) for `+` and `%20` for spaces

Comment: If the string goes into a query parameter (or a POST form body - anything with MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), then `+` is actually a valid (and often-used) encoding for a space. (However, if it goes into the path portion, you do need `%20`.)

Comment: Also, the remarks for `Http.UrlEncode` in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netcore-3.1) explain that too, and that you can use `Http.UrlPathEncode` for the case where you need `%20` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
string str = "sample text";
string url = Uri.EscapeDataString(str);
```