# Need help converting bbcode URLs that contain spaces to valid markdown

Tags: c#, mysql, regex, markdown, bbcode

As part of some data migration I'm converting user content from bbcode to markdown.

I'm doing the conversion in a custom MySQL 8.0.22 function, which contains the following line to convert bbcode `[url]` tags to markdown:

```
...
SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[url=([^\\]]+)\\](.*?)\\[\\/url\\]', '[$2]($1)', 1, 0, 'i');
...
```

This performs as expected, for example:

`[url=https://stackoverflow.com/]SO[/url]` converts corectly to `[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)`

The problem is: some of the URLs contain spaces, which isn't valid markdown and isn't displaying correctly on my client-side.

Is it possible to modify my `REGEXP_REPLACE` statement to replace spaces in the links with "%20"?

I'd like to do it all in MySQL if possible, but can do the processing on each record in C# if necessary.

---

For completeness, my entire bbcode to markdown function is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `func_bb_to_md`(bbcode MEDIUMTEXT) RETURNS mediumtext CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE markdown MEDIUMTEXT;
    SET markdown = bbcode;
    
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[code\\](.*?)\\[\\/code\\]', '`$1`', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[url\\](.*?)\\[\\/url\\]', '<$1>', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[url=([^\\]]+)\\](.*?)\\[\\/url\\]', '[$2]($1)', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[img\\](.*?)\\[\\/img\\]', '![]($1)', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[yt\\](.*?)\\[\\/yt\\]', '![]($1)', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[b\\](.*?)\\[\\/b\\]', '**$1**', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[i\\](.*?)\\[\\/i\\]', '*$1*', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[u\\](.*?)\\[\\/u\\]', '$1', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, '[list]', ''); 
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, '[list=1]', ''); 
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, '[/list]', ''); 
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, '[*]', '* '); 
    
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[color=([^\\]]+)\\](.*?)\\[\\/color\\]', '$2', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\[quote\\](.*?)\\[\\/quote\\]', '> $1', 1, 0, 'i'); 
    
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':)', '{{slightly_smiling_face}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ';)', '{{wink}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':D', '{{grin}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':P', '{{stuck_out_tongue}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':(', '{{frowning_face}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':''(', '{{cry}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':.', '{{flushed}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':|', '{{neutral_face}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':O', '{{open_mouth}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':@', '{{angry}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':S', '{{confused}}');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, ':$', '{{blush}}');
    SET markdown = REGEXP_REPLACE(markdown, '\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}', ':$1:', 1, 0, 'i');
    
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, '\r\n', '\n');
    SET markdown = REPLACE(markdown, '\n', '\r\n');

    RETURN markdown;
END
```

Comment: In C#, that would be `Regex.Replace(markdown, @"(?i)\[url=([^]]+)](.*?)\[/url]', x => $"[{x.Groups[2].Value}]({x.Groups[1].Value.Replace(" ", "%20")})")`. Perhaps, instead of using `.Replace`, you might want `Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Groups[1].Value)` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517709/3832970)).

Comment: I'll give that a go if there's no way to do it in MySQL, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you may use `Regex.Replace` with a match evaluator to manipulate the captured texts. In MySQL `REGEXP_REPLACE`, you do not have this option.

So, you can use

```cs
var markdown = "[url=https://stackoverflow.com/a b]SO[/url]";
var p = @"(?i)\[url=([^]]+)](.*?)\[/url]";
var result = Regex.Replace(markdown, p, x => 
        $"[{x.Groups[2].Value}]({x.Groups[1].Value.Replace(" ","%20")})");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See [this C# demo online](https://ideone.com/hURhgY).

The `(?i)\[url=([^]]+)](.*?)\[/url]` regex matches (in a case insensitive way) `[url=`, captures any one or more chars other than `]` into Group 1, then `[/url]` substring. The match is passed to the match evaluator, `x` is a match object. `$"[{x.Groups[2].Value}]({x.Groups[1].Value.Replace(" ","%20")})")` does all the necessary manipulation.

Comment: I was fairly sure there was no way to do it purely in MySQL, so I'll use this approach to convert the bbcode links to valid URLs, before converting to markdown.

Thanks!