# Visual Studio 2010 - Debugging / Build Problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2010 and the Team Foundation Server Express (beta). My VS Project (C#.Net / WPF) has been migrated from VS 2008 (without TFS) to VS 2010 (with TFS).

Whenever I apply changes to my code and try to debug my application, I get messages like `This breakpoint will not be hit.` (in german: `Der Haltepunkt wird momentan nicht erreicht. Der Quellcode weist Unterschiede zur Originalversion auf.`) and the project is started using the old executable version (the one with the last successful build). No errors occure, the code is OK, but the changes are not applied either.

When I manually cleanup and rebuild my project, everything works quite fine - but there has to be a fix for this issue?

---

**Edit:** I just added a new project to my VS solution and checked it in on the TFS Server. Using this new project the problem does not occure. Even when I add the same dependencies I used in the project mentioned above, the debugging and building of the new project works fine without the errors mentioned above.

Maybe this information helps you to lead me to a solution.

Comment: I faced the same problem. But doing this solved my problem : In property pages of the project, go to start options, and mark native code. it worked for me. I hope it does for you too.

Comment: Hum, thank you for your suggestion, but I was not able to solve the problem this way. +1 anyway for trying ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear whether existing answers are not sufficient.  I can't know exactly what's causing your problem; but, I can detail some places this potentially comes up.

The first area that I commonly see this is when a project references an assembly directly.  You can create a project that creates an assembly.  Another project might use that assembly and you can reference by assembly directly (and not add a reference to the "project").  This disconnects VS from really knowing it needs to "build" that referenced assembly first and it will sometimes get out of sync with the debugging symbols (PDB).  You can tell if a project has been referenced or an assembly has been referenced in the properties of the reference (expand References in Solution Explorer, right-click a reference, and select Properties).  A referenced project will not have a Specific Version property, while an assembly reference will.  You can sometimes also tell from Project\Project Dependencies.  If you have a reference to an assembly generated by another project but that project isn't a dependency in Project Dependencies, it might be an assembly reference.  To fix this, you can usually just delete the reference and add a reference to the project.

I've also find that sometimes breakpoints confuses the debugger.  If I have many breakpoints or they've been kicking around a long time, the debugger sometimes does some weird things.  If I delete all the existing break points (Debug/Delete all breakpoints) and re-apply them the debugger is usually much happier.

Comment: I just checked all used references but could not find any error. However - removing and re-adding all dependencies solved the problem anyway. I'll mark this post as the answer as it's the reply which fits best.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo). The assemblies might be in GAC or a project or some projects need to be rebuild to generate the pdb files again, which are used for debugging. If you don't choose to rebuild it might use the old pdb files.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are putting breaking points somewhere your program can't access them.

Ex:

```
const int x = 5;

if(this.x == 1)
   //do something <--- breakpoint here
```

Comment: no, this is not the problem. I even added a break point in the first line of the main window constructor and the message occured. After manually cleaning up and rebuilding the project, everything worked fine (as described in my initial question).

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a mixed mode application (unmanaged native C++ & managed C#), make sure to set `Enable unmanaged code debugging` in your C# application's Properties window.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild, there isn't an easier way around it.

The program database files (PDB) need to be recreated. You should also have your configuration setting set to debug.

Also the first answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo) must be of help as well.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I started VS as an admin, and it also happened to me when the project is set to a different architecture than a DLL that I used in this project.