# Attach to process: the breakpoint will not be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, attach-to-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

I'm trying to debug a running app on an installation, that I have previously debugged, but now I'm getting:

> The breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

The DLL is hosted in another app, that I do not have access to, so I'm using attach to process. But like I mentioned I have debugged this way before.

It is Visual Studio 2010 .net 4.0 class library project.
Any ideas? 
Restarting VS doesn't seem to help