# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I am struggling with breakPoint issue in VS 2012 for more than hours. I am from eclipse background, there I never heard about such issues.

**Problem :**

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
> for this document.

I have placed the break point in `click` action of `Jquery`.

[image]

I found the issue using the IE script debugging., The file loaded was old file., i.e I have modified a lot, but I can see no changes in the one which is loaded in IE. How to fix the bug

**What I have Tried :**

I know this question is duplicate, but being a **newbie to VS and C#**., I could not understand the older answers.  For example, [in this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo#answer-2155997) he told to choose Debug -> Windows -> Modules. But I doesn't have Modules under windows in VS 2012. Also even though I read, I could not understand the explanation.

Also I am quite new to term `Assemblies` and `PDB`. Though, I located PDB files as he said. But how to open the .pdb file?

**Need :**
Could anyone explain me the same answer in easier term (with more explanation).

Comment: Maybe describe your specific situation and problem better. The message appears when your code is not loaded/executed.

Comment: This doesn't look related to C#. It's related to debugging JavaScript with Visual Studio.

Comment: That makes a lot of difference. PDB and Assemblies are not relevant for JavaScript.

Comment: check if the asp.net development server instance is running even after the vs is not in a running mode(ctrl f5). if so then stop the development server and run the solution again.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I found the issue using the IE script debugging., The file loaded was old file., i.e I have modified a lot, but I can see  no changes in the one which is loaded in IE.  How to fix the bug??

Comment: Start by hitting Ctrl+F5 in the browser.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hooooo. That doesn't resolved my break point issue. But instead of putting breakpoint at javascript, now I put in c# code (new C# code, which is not previously not loaded in IE). Hence I can `watch` there in newly loaded code. Hence somehow my problem is fixed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixing "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

Comment: I had the same issue debugging javascript code in visual studio. I launch the web page in internet explorer and it worked fine. You can try the same.

Answer (score 7):

I found this out by accident with my VS2012 and ASP.NET MVC, maybe it can help somebody. I noticed that breakpoints in javascript that's inline in the *.cshtml file like this won't get hit (note that this file is a cshtml file):

[image]

But breakpoints in external *.js files will get hit:

[image]

Comment: I'm currently having this problem with an external *.JS file so apparently it's not quite that simple.

Comment: @MikeFulton, darn it, sorry to hear that. That is frustrating because it's hard to rely on the browser's developer tools. I was working on a project a few months ago that used React.js and I was using Chrome's React debugger add-in almost exclusively because VS was no help.

Comment: Works for me, thanks. This is the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

Try to add `debugger;` key word before `$.getJSON` 
Also make sure if you use IE to un-check the disable script debugging

Internet Options> Advanced tab> Under Browsing.

As I think this issue is related to Javascript debugging not C#

Answer (score 6):

This results for me:

In your web application make sure **Silverlight** and **ASP.NET** debugger are **enabled**.

How to get there?

=> Right click on the Web Application => Properties => Web tab. Under Debuggers section make sure **Silverlight** and **ASP.NET** are **enabled**.

Comment: This works for you for debugging JavaScript without any actual Silverlight being involved?

Comment: I'm using VS 2017.  ASP.NET debugger was enabled but Silverlight wasn't.  I enabled Silverlight and my breakpoint was hit!  The last time I said "Silverlight", let alone used it, was 2008.  Thanks to the tip!

Answer (score 5):

Running Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015 RC, I've found that to get a breakpoint to work in a .js file I need two things to be true:

1. I need to start Visual Studio by right-clicking the VS shortcut and select "Run as administrator".  (If right-clicking on the Taskbar icon, select the application shortcut icon from the pop-up menu and right-click on that to get a context menu that includes "Run as administrator".)
2. I need to set Internet Explorer as the default browser that will be opened for the web debugging session.  If I choose Chrome or Firefox, the breakpoint doesn't work for me.

Comment: I ran into this issue with VS 2017.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

After opening and closing VS, rebooting the PC with all with no chance, this workaround worked for me in VS 2012 ( Ver 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL ):

In Project **Property Pages**, under **Start Options**, in **Debugger** section, only **ASP.NET** was enabled. As soon as I enabled **Native Code** and **SQL Server**, that red circle with plus sign inside, enabled again.
No idea why this worked! No active connection in **Server Explorer** nor using any native code in the project!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You can use VS2017 to debug JS code this way.

When you set VS to launch the browser (Chrome in my case), it opens a new Chrome window. I was trying to debug the specific code (different URL from the window that opened) in a new tab. So I had the 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound' in VS.

I found out that if I opened the new URL in the original tab it suddenly worked. Seems that VS is tied to that particular tab.

Hope this helps.

These are the particulars of my situation: VS 2017 - Mainly C# code with some embedded HTML/JS which I needed to debug, Chrome (Version 68.0.3440), Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

As this is Javascript code, so you need to use a javascript debugger. Generally internet browsers come with a debugger/inspector menu, which allows you to inspect/debug your javascript easily. Such debuggers come with a lot of useful features such as HTTP request/response inspection, browser session/local storage, etc.

Comment: But it's JavaScript? How (and why) would that need compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is "Modules" option, but it's enabled only when you are in debug mode.
You can just press Ctrl+D,M combination when you're in debug.
In few words, PDB is a file that contains all debug information about your assebmly, you can not debug an assembly without this file. Assembly is a file that contains precompiled code for exetuion via CLR.
Could you provide a bit more information about your problem. What kind of application you are trying to debug for example?
Also, if you have located you pdb files made EXACTLY for your assembly, you can load it by right-clicking your assembly in modules window and selecting **Load Symbols From > Symbol Path**

Comment: How would this be relevant to debugging JavaScript?  There is no assembly or PDB for JavaScript files because they are interpreted at runtime, not compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all breakpoints and restarting debugging in Visual Studio.