# Debug Typescript with breakpoints in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

i use typescript 0.8.3.1 in an mvc4 project in VS2012.

I can set breakpoints in the ts file but when i debug in internet explorer VS says

```
 The breakpoint will not be currently hit. No symobls are loaded for this document.
```

Also refreshing the page does not solve it.

Comment: Try 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo

Comment: this is more a typescript thing. The breakpoints in the generated js files are hit but not in the ts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: enable "generate Sourcemap" in options-> web essentials -> typescript