# Debug a Silverlight svc Service

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Ok I saw that many questions do have been asked before, but not one of the answered solutions will solve my problem.

I have created a silverlight application which uses some Database calls. I have 4 or 5 different calls to a database. 4 of those worked as expected, the last one will throw a crossdomain exception. But its the same Database only a different table.

On my development machine everything included the last database call is working. after publishing it I will got the crossdoamin error. I have the policy files in my root of the webservice. No difference.

So I tryed to remotedebug my app. But here my problem starts. I can set breakpoints in the normal page codes, but if I try to set a breakpoint in the Servcie I see that the breakpoints are greyd out so they will never be hit.

I dont have any idea what I am doing wrong, maybe someone can help me.

I use VS 2010 and Silverlight 5

I also have tried this http://cedricboudoya.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/how-to-debug-a-wcf-service/

but this doesnt work at all.

Regards Martin

Answer (score 0):

That link seems to be the right way to do it.

Put a breakpoint in your normal code just before it goes off to the service, then (Ctrl + Alt + P) - Attach to process and choose the database (In the type column it should read something like T-SQL, Managed)

The breakpoints should now become available and be hit when the program is resumed.

If this doesn't work, try reading around this area [Fixing "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

Good luck!