# Windows Phone 8 SDK doesn't refresh XAML part of a page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm working on an app for Windows Phone 8 and I'm debugging it on my Nokia Lumia 925. But every time I press F5, the XAML code stays the same while my c# code refreshes - so I've got the new code, but the UI is the same. I have to reinstall the app every time to get the changes on my phone.

Any ideas how I could fix that? Thanks!

Comment: This is a well known bug from 2013 2012 and 2010 as well. Just rebuild and deploy. Thats all you can do.

Comment: That's a pity, but well... thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you debug, make sure to first `Rebuild` the app. Also you may encounter issues such as "[Symbols not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)" from the ".pdb" extension in your debug folder. In that case you can do two things to resolve the issue:

- Goto your project's `Bin/Debug`folder and delete all the items.
- Or just do `Clean Solution` each time before you debug the app.

In this way, you can deploy the most updated version of your code into your Emulator/Device and avoid any [missing symbols errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo). Hope that helps.