# VS 2013 the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

VS2013, windows 8.1, windows phone 8 c# app
Breakpoints not working and i got  the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document error
what i need to do?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixing "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

Comment: What breakpoint are you trying to hit? are you sure your not setting it on a line of code that will be optimised out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build your project, if it is build be sure that you attach to right process ! If you are sure that this 2 are okay, clean the solution and rebuild again.

Answer (score 11):

I struggled forever trying to fix this. Finally this is what did it for me.

*Select* **Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> General**

*Tick* **Enable .NET Framework source stepping.**

(This may be all you need to do but if you are like me, you also have to do the ones stated below. The below solution will also fix errors where your project is loading old assemblies/.pdb files despite rebuilding and cleaning.)

*Select*  **Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run**,

*Untick* **Only Build startup projects and dependencies on Run**,

*Select* **Always Build** from the **On Run, when project are out of date** dropdown.

Comment: I would give this answer more then 1n like if I could. After searching for 3 frekin days. This is the only thing that helped me.

Comment: Don't forget to clean and rebuild after doing these.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this means that any of your assemblies has changed but was not not re-built, or to be more precise the Debug-Information-File (PDB) is not recent. Therefor the debugger does not know the right source-text and therefor cannot step into. Rebuilt the assemblies and attach it to the right process.

Also you may take into consideration that assemblies built for .NET 3.5 downwards may not be processed together with assemblies for .NET 4.0 upwards, you cannot debug both types at the same time.

EDIT: To ensure what I mentioned before check which type of assembly the debug-info is generated for. When attaching your assembly to an existing process press the select-button behind "attach to". There you can select the right type if not automatically done.

Comment: rebuilding are not help me. any other variants?

Comment: Have you also checked that target-versions are compatible (see the second paragraph from my post). I had this issue before, was trying to debug a .NET 3.5. assembly while debugging within 4.0-one.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to kill IIS (if used (ASP.Net)) and to close and restart Visual Studio.
It maybe sounds very stupid but also sometimes it helps to just reboot.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem when i faced was to disconnect the Team foundation server(TMS) - Since i am using it - , and to re publish the website.

Answer (score 0):

For me even the latest code changes also not get effected in the application. Therefore I made a small compilation error in the code where breakpoints are located then try to run the solution after clean build. It hits the error and then I correct the error and run it again, now even it hits the breakpoints.