# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document. when debussing dll

Tags: c#, debugging, dll

I get the above mentioned error when trying to add a breakpoint in a dll.
I have tried all off the options mentioned here:  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

Background:

1. I am using vs2013 community edition
2. The class in the dll is static
3. dll project is included in my solution I have tried to uncheck
   "enable just my code"
4. The module windows reports that the symbols has
   been loaded.
5. The dll's pdb file is located in the bin/debug folder
   where the exe is
6. I have also tried to check "enable native code
   debugging"

When I enable "native code debugging" the modules window shows its trying to load the dll twice, first time it succeeds and the second time it fails. I have attached a screen shot of this.

[image: Visual studio window]

Is there anything I can try to fix this issue?

The following is a quick description of the projects in the solution.

1. CustomAppInitioator - standalone app
2. CustomCode - Test application for dll, I modify the program.cs to only start a form for each dll
3. CustomCodeDLL - DLL project contain separate classes, eachsuing the namespace customcode.something, each class has its own .cs file
4. CustomConnectorDLL - dll project for database
5. CustomEmailDLL - DLL project for emails
6. CustomIconsDLL - Empty dll project containing an public resource file for icons

Item 2 is the startup project, and I only include on the current test form item 3's class. So 1, 4-6 is not applicable here, I think....

Comment: are you certain that your dll project is build for the last time?

Comment: Is this a Silverlight project by any chance?

Comment: Can you show the properties for the reference between your startup project `CustomCode` and `CustomCodeDLL`? Is `CustomCode` copying the reference through every time?

Comment: slugster, what do you mean the referance between the startup project and the dll? Do you want to see the main code?

Comment: Expand the references node of CustomCode in the solution explorer, right click on the CuctomCodeDLL reference, select Properties - what does it say?

Comment: Just wanted to comment quick. i was having this problem and found out it was because the c++ dll was compiling for x64 but the c# was set to any cpu (it was defaulting to x32) so changed it to x64 and can now debug the c++ code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was with the merging of dlls. Some of the class require their own dll's I merge all of this into one dll. If I remove this, I can debug in my dll.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the dll is not up-to-date. Here are the steps how I always try to resolve it:

- rebuild your solution and check the ddl created date in the output folder (usually 'bin') if its 'now'
- if not now then you need to check the paths
- you can also check if all your projects are set to 'Build' during the bild
- check whether you reference the rigt dll/project in the Properties window.

Comment: That dll is the most up to date in that folder.

Comment: Because it's the CustomCode.dll's bin folder. I think it's a wrong screenshot. The actual newest exe must be somewhere else.

Comment: Check my comment on the answer above

Answer (score 0):

I think your dll project does not Build for the last time, you can Build manually this, or set this setting (for visual studio 2012-2013)

Tools -> Option -> Project And Solution -> Build And Run ->
Then uncheck the "only build startup projects and dependencies on run"

Comment: I have manually build it each time, does nothing. I have even tried to add a public variable to the static class. Build it and i can see it immediately in the main exe program code.

Comment: have you tried to close the CS file and re-open it??

Comment: Not as per say. But if I am not debugging and I press f12 on the code, it just straight to my code which I want to debug. If I am debugging and I press f12 over the code, it jumps to that locked metadata view of only the function headings

Comment: Scratch that, it only jumps straight to the metadata view, if I am debugging or not. It did not do this yesterday. Yesterday it was as above