# "The breakpoint will not currently be hit" - and I cannot add the .pdb file

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with one project in Visual Studio **2013 (Visual C++)**.

But when I build it in `debug` mode, then **run it in `debug`** mode I get:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

I was trying to fix it in analogical way to what people suggested for Visual C# [Fixing "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

Unfortunately, **none** of that worked:

- clean & rebuild solution (also with manually deleted temporary files),
- `solution -> Properties -> Startup Project -> startup projects -> Start action`,
- `Debug/General settings` -> uncheck `Just My Code`,
- quit VC++, reload, restart PC.

Then I've tried to select the `.pdb` file (after `clear, rebuild`) with `Debug -> Windows -> Modules` and `RMB -> Load symbols`. `v120.pdb` was in `/Solution/Debug` folder and `.exe` was in `/Bin` folder. I've chosen it and I got an error message:

> A matching symbol file was not found in this folder.

**What else can I do?** Which solution/project options may have affected debugging? I build an `x86 .exe` project that include some of my `.lib` files (but the debugging doesn't work even in `main.cpp`).

---

### Additional information (some were requested by users in comments):

I see that under `Debug -> Windows -> Modules` there is such entry for my `.exe`:

> Project.exe   F:...exe   **N/A   N/A Binary was not built with debug information.**      1       12/15/2014 12:31 PM 00BA0000-00E9C000   [3504] Project.exe

That's quite strange because the `Solution/Debug` folder **is being created each time I hit `Rebuild`** for `Debug` mode, and so I get new `.pdb` file also. I am running the application with `Debug` mode selected.

---

The value of `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format`  is `Program Database for Edit And Continue (/ZI)`.

Comment: Whats you value for 'Debug Information Format' when you right click you project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General?

Comment: @mikeVine `Program Database for Edit And Continue (/ZI)` - updated the question.

Comment: ok thats fine - what about Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info and its associated path?

Comment: Does it hit the breakpoint if you launch and debug from within visual studio, i.e. `F5`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you're not properly generating debug information which is what the modules window is telling you. Make sure that the following properties are both set up:

`Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format`

and

`Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Information.`

These can sometimes get change accidentally.

I've never seen this information get lost without a good cause though unless you've got a custom build solution

Comment: That's IT! For some reason, `Generate Debug Information` was an empty value (neither `YES` or `NO`). I don't remember to mess with `Linker`. But I **did** created a project with some custom Wizard (both `Debug` and `Release` build targets was created). Thank you, sir - it was agonizing me for hours before I've posted the question :)