# VS C++ All of a sudden no symbols, cannot debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I was debugging fine just yesterday, woke up this morning and all of a sudden I can't use breakpoints. I tried rebuilding, I made sure I was using the right exe and dlls.

What should I do?

-I didn't change configuration settings. I have it on debug.

-When I press F5, it runs, does not promt anything. The only thing is that when I place a breakpoint it says (while hovering over the break point) "no symbols loaded for this document."

-I did not move any files around.

Attept to figure it out: Changed something in the code, looks like that changes was not reflected in the dll, maybe I'm in fact not using the correct files, will look into it...

Comment: Are you certain you're building a debug configuration?  Maybe you accidentally switched to release.  I'd check that, then rebuild all.

Comment: I didn't change configuration settings. I have it on debug.

Comment: When you hit "F5" (Run) does it prompt you that your build is out of date, or does it start running?  Also, make sure you haven't moved a file (e.g. the original was under one folder but you moved (copied) it to another folder, but you are setting your breakpoint in the original location, which is no longer valid???)

Comment: When I press F5, it runs, does not promt anything. The only thing is that when I place a breakpoint it says (while hovering over the break point) "no symbols loaded for this document." I did not move any files around.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo

Answer (score 0):

Alright sorry, figured it out...

Turns out there were TWO dlls, one old version, one new, and my exe was referring to the old version.

Sooo to answer my question: Do a search for all related files to your project, make doubly sure all old files of old builds are deleted. Try changing the code. If changes are not reflected, you know those changes are not going into files you're using.