# Multiple errors after switching from VS 2010 to 2013

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I maintain a website using Visual Studio 2010, asp.net, and vb.net for the code-behind. Yesterday my software was switched over to Visual Studio 2013 and I converted my 2010 project to the 2013 platform. Initially, the switch didn't seem to cause any unexpected errors. This morning, however, I have been unable to debug the program using breakpoints. I receive this error:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

I have checked other stackoverflow questions and have tried multiple solutions, such as:

1. Cleaning and rebuilding application
2. Rebooting Visual Studio and running as administrator
3. Deleting Telerik references and then adding them again
4. Checking to make sure debug = true is set in Web Config
5. Turning Ajax to false to check if any different errors were received or fixed
6. Checking that asp.net option in debugging is true
7. Checking the options window for anything out of place

After all of this, the error still persists. I think it may have to due with some file not using .NET framework 4.5 and using 4.0 instead, but I am not sure how I would check this. Is there a for-all method where it will set *all* files to 4.5 framework instead of raking through each file and checking/changing?

### EDIT

Matt Wilko's comment made me realize I forgot to add in another item that I tried. The answer on another stackoverflow question suggested deleting old .pdb files. Then you look at the symbol load information and compare that to the locations of the actual .pdb file.

I had tried this previously and I had 6 .pdb files located across 4 backup files, inside a debug folder within a backup folder, and then inside the bin folder. The symbol load information was searching inside the IIS, temp asp.net files folder, my local symbol cache, and then various Telerik folders. It is searching for Telerik.Web.UI.pdb and there is an error that states:

```
Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

However, the answer did not clearly specify how to rectify the situation. How do I point the symbol load information to the accurate folder where the .pdb files are being kept? Which file do I delete and keep?

### EDIT 2

As a workaround for not being able to debug in Visual Studio 2013, I have copied my code and went back to 2010 to test. Now I am wanting to publish in 2013 after testing my program and I receive an error that states:

```
Could not find file obj/Release/Package/PackageTemp/bin/myproject.xml
```

I go to this location and the file in question is present. How do I fix this error? I am growing rather weary of all of the errors I am receiving in VS 2013. Should I just reinstall the entire thing?

Comment: Framework version is set on projects not files.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant to say.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixing "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

Comment: Have a look in the .suo file. It's where break points are stored, might be wroth editing them out if there are any.

Comment: When you go to build your project, check the "Output" window, and see when that particular message comes up - it should give you more detail as to why your breakpoints cannot be loaded.

Comment: @X3074861X I checked the output window and I am receiving about 300 JavaScript exceptions. Other than that I am not seeing anything breakpoint related. I have 5 breakpoints set at page load, submit, and 3 different methods. None of them are being hit.

Comment: @MattWilko The answer to that question didn't solve my problem. I still cannot hit the breakpoints. I deleted old .pdb files but when I check the folder again there are more there. Is there only supposed to be 1?

Comment: Typically the VS output window will reference an assembly, followed by the message "could not load debug symbols for...", followed by a message as to why that occurred. Have you tried just deleting your bin and obj folders?

Comment: @X3074861X I have not tried that. I was unsure if it would break anything. I'll give it a go real quick.

Comment: @X3074861X Okay, I deleted both the bin and obj folder and proceeded to clean/rebuild. I got multiple errors regarding namespaces and types not being defined. I also received warnings about the assembly not being located and references not being resolved.

Comment: That's likely part of your problem. What exactly is missing? If you go to your "References" folder in your project, are you missing any assembly references? They would show a warning sign next to them.

Comment: @X3074861X Project-related classes were missing as well as some 3rd party software references, like iTextpad. I decided to overwrite the project with the newest version of the project in my source control. This fixed the errors I was getting. There were also no warning signs next to the references.