# Using Microsoft debugger with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

There's an option in the Android project settings in the **Android Options** section on the **Packaging** tab that lets you choose between the Xamarin debugger or the Microsoft debugger. The Xamarin debugger works, but not as good as the Microsoft one might. Unfortunately I get an error message when trying to use the Microsoft debugger and deploy on one of the Visual Studio Android Emulators.

> Unable to start debugging. Non-debuggable application installed on the target device. Required file '/data/data/My.Application/lib/gdbserver' could not be found on the device. Please install a debuggable version.

Is there any way to get the Microsoft debugger to work?

Comment: As for my tests before, the Microsoft debugger never worked with xamarin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xamarin debugger can only debug managed (i.e. C#) code. Breakpoints only work with the Xamarin debugger if the project being debugged is a managed project. They don't work if the project is a native app or native library.

The Microsoft debugger can only debug native (i.e. C/C++) code. Breakpoints only work with the Microsoft debugger if the project being debugged is a native app or native library, or if it is attached to an already-running Android process.

To get gdbserver into the app package, you either have to reference a native code library from your managed app, or include it (with build action set to AndroidNativeLibrary).  I found you can also add a link to gdbserver (again, with build action set to AndroidNativeLibrary) from a project and make use of path sniffing to select the gdbserver from the matching ABI.  Snippet of project file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT)\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver\gdbserver">
      <Link>lib\armeabi-v7a\gdbserver</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Also please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322392/295046) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31576721/295046).