# Xamarin.Forms: Android breakpoints not hit

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2022, and since then, I can't hit breakpoints any longer during Android shared project debugging, even if they seems to be loaded correctly.
I've set debugType on Pdb only on both projects.
Tried clean/rebuilding many times, remove app and restart emulator but still no luck. Any idea about this issue?
I'm using XF 5.0.0.2337.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [officail community said](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/breakpoint-not-hit-debugging-xamarin-android-proje/1561025):

Enable **Use Fast Deployment** on the Android project.

Comment: Works for mac as well !

Comment: Works! Also the exact opposite of what I had to do to get this working in previous versions https://stackoverflow.com/a/39275428/730132.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Samsung device (Samsung Experience is 9.5) and now the breakpoint works again. Fast deployment/restarting/re-installing was not enough.