# Debugger not working in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

My debugger stopped working as expected in Visual Studio Community 2015 (Update 1).

The solution I'm working on has the following architecture:

1. "Query" project - written with angularjs 1.4
2. "Login" project - written with angularjs 1.4
3. More back-end projects - written with c#/web-api

I run the Query project, it checks for session and redirect to Login. After the login is successful it makes another redirect back to the Query url. 
Until yesterday I had no issues debugging the whole solution from VS directly. 
Now the behavior is that the first time I run the "Query" project, my breakpoints get hit. After coming back from Login, no breakpoint is hit.

Both client-side projects are hosted using IIS Express.

Things I tried until now:

- clean, build, rebuild the solution;
- attaching to process from VS. I attached to all IIS Express processes but with no luck;
- closing VS and deleting my bin and obj folders from all projects;
- restarting the machine;

Also good to mention that I have set in web.config:

```
 <compilation debug="true"></compilation>
```

Any hint or idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: uload the project and reload, or exlude the file from the project and include it,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying more different solutions, the only thing that worked in my case was to unload/reload the project. 
Also, now the breakpoints that I set before the application runs are no longer getting hit, but if I set them after the application started then they work fine.

Comment: Debug/Delete all breakpoints, then try adding the breakpoints again, even before you start to debug - see if that works

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest some Stack Overflow answers related to this issue, maybe it helps:

1. New project and just importing the files into it: [Upgrade to Visual Sudio 2015 and now can't hit break points in debuging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644074/upgrade-to-visual-sudio-2015-and-now-cant-hit-break-points-in-debuging)
2. Manual check of the Symbol Load Information: [Fixing "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)
3. Incorrect configuration selected in the debug menu: [Visual Studio breakpoints not being hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582022/visual-studio-breakpoints-not-being-hit)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Vs2019) the Microsoft Symbol server was causing the issue.

It was not being able to attach Local IIS.

Enabling only the NuGet Symbol server and disabling the Microsoft worked for me