# Pdb file of Library not loaded into Application's bin folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have a solution with an application and a library. When debugging - breakpoints don't work and I've found (with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155997/939213)) that it's because the **pdb** file of the library isn't copied into the application's **debug** folder.

I can change the output folder manually in Properties - Build - Output. But that seems like the wrong way. Visual Studio is supposed to do that automatically.

So: How do I fix Visual Studio to copy the pdb file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not have a reference to the project, but to the DLL only.
Try to delete the reference to the library and add it again. Make sure you don't select the DLL as reference but select the project from from the reference manager:

[image]

Comment: +1. Very good! Now it's copying it. But not to where VS is looking for it (a folder named `AppX` inside the debug folder). Strange.

Comment: you know that you can set the build output folders for each build type (debug, release, ...) individually? Maybe you changed just one of them.