# Null Reference Exception on an instantiated object that I cannot step into

Tags: .net, nullreferenceexception

On this web application's login page, it refers to a few different other projects to verify their credentials based on the 'pStrFacilityCode' variable. For some reason, this line with the breakpoint is throwing a Null Reference Exception and I cannot step into it. If I go and manually open the code file and find `mCheckUSer` and set a breakpoint in VS it says this breakpoint will not be hit as no symbol has been loaded.

[image]

As you can see from the watch window, all of the objects are not null. I've re-built the child projects and re-add their DLLs to the parent project's references. I've cleaned and re-built. Running out of ideas here... Anyone know what else I can try?

Comment: [Fixing “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

Comment: Hmm, the .pdb generated is much older than the .dll. I'll try clearing that all and trying again.