# Can't debug Web Api in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, debug-symbols

I'm having an issue in Visual Studio 2012 that don't allow me to set breakpoints in my code and debug it.

[image]

As you can it in the image, the compiler is telling me that I don't have symbols loaded and, taking a look at "Modules" in the Debug tab, I can see that there are some of my dll's symbols that where not located properly and I don't know why because I installed all by using nuget.

[image]

I did all the suggestions made on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo) post (clean and rebuild, I set the debug info as 'full', I disable 'Just My Code' checkbox, I deleted the ASP.NET temporary files, etc) but I could not hit this breakpoint at the moment. It seems that is not finding the .pdb files correctly, where I can find those?

Answer (score 1):

Have experienced exactly the same in VS2013, and I just hit it again.

I had other REST API entry points in the same projects, which were still working, so in the end - last time - I renamed the API/controller, created a new API and shifted the logic over there, which in the end seemed to work. Only a workaround, but at least something if you're stuck.

This second time around I tookkind of a nuke approach: started quitting/restarting VS, excluded the class with the REST API, did a clean + rebuild on the project + solution, included the class again, plus clean and rebuild. ... perhaps some VS-restart again. Ultimately it got synced and I was able to load and debug the api.

far from ideal, but in case you just want to force past it I guess.

You could also upgrade and try the VS2015 (free version) - subject to the size / fetaures of your project - and see if it handles the issue better. (I've installed it next to my VS2013 pro).

Comment: forgot to mention, to me it happened when I changed the parameter list to an api that's been around/working for months.

Comment: In my case, the problem was that I had my WebApi controllers in a separate project, so I solved it by going to solution properties, and selecting multiple projects to startup, in my case both UI and WebAPI project.