# The breakpoint will not currently be hit, no symbols have been loaded for this document - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I have this issue. I have seen others post about the same thing. I have tried every solution that I have found on each post I've seen.

- I've cleaned and re-built.
- I've gone to the solution properties and updated the configuration to 'Debug' from 'Release' (took several tries to get this to stick).
- I've gone through Tools > Options > Debugging > General and unchecked the box for 'Enable Just My Code'.
- I've cleaned and rebuilt after each change, then made sure that my change was still in effect before continuing.

With most of these changes it would work once, but when I would close the web page (which I would need to in my testing) and then re-open it the break points would stop working and give me this error. Every time I would come back to see if I could find something else to help. I've run out of options and really need this to work.

This is a project that is using VS 2013, Run in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m, and using .net 4.0. The code is in my desktop, a fresh pull from GIT, I have windows 7 on a dell i7 Optiplex 790.

Comment: Configuration must be in debug for breakpoints to hit. Is this standard aspnet code that you are debugging? webforms? a controller?

Comment: Take a look at this question´s answers and comments. Might help, check the modules, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but adding a place for caching the symbols allowed them to load. Originally this was blank. Now it seems to be working. Even though it doesn't appear to be actually using the folder I set. I have started and restarted the project a couple of times and the break points will still be hit.
Thanks to @Ernesto I did go through that question, but there wasn't anything there that I had not already tried or that I could try.

Comment: I'm going to close this since it seems to have been fixed. I have not had the error since adding a place for the symbols, even though it is still empty.