# Visual Studio 2015 No debug symbols loaded. Cannot set breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Hi I recently upgraded to visual studio 2015. For some reason in only my MVC Web project (all other projects are debug-able). I sometimes cannot debug and now its stuck in this mode. And for some reason there is 0 modules loaded in the modules list. Anyone know what can be wrong?

Things I have already tried:

- Clean Solution. Delete all obj files and bin files. Rebuild.
- Fix all warnings and update all packages to the same version. Rebuild.

[image: No symbols loaded?]

The debug symbols are back again sporadically. But disappears most of the time. It does not seem like its a code change or that restarting works repeatedly. I put a breakpoint in the application_start code and just take the opportunity to debug when ever i get the lucky chance lol.

[image: This is how it is supposed to look]

Comment: Is there a PDB file in the output directory?

Comment: there are tons of answers in this question, I hope it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo

Comment: yes there are PDB files in the output directory they dont seem to be used for some reason.

Comment: You'll need to get your machine fixed.  Start by disabling the shrink-wrapped malware, if it is Avast then get rid of it asap.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant i don't run any anti virus programs on my machine. So its not that I think, and my coworker is also running Windows10 so I do not think its the OS.