# the breakpoint will not currently be hit at Vs 2015

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

In my **WCF** project at **Vs 2015** when I add break point for **debugging** I got this message:

```
the breakpoint will not currently be hit no symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

I do googleing and none of other's answer worked for me !!!
for example: `Right click the Solution in solution explorer, click "clean solution", this deletes all the compiled and temporary files associated with a solution.`

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301216/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-d) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445717/vs2015-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for)

any suggestion?

thank you

Comment: While in debug mode go to `Debug -> Windows -> Modules` in the Visual Studio menu. Here is a list of all loaded modules and their symbols. Now look for the name of your .exe or .dll. What does the "Symbol Status" say?

Answer (score 0):

If your solution is having shared projects with other solutions which is also open then close the other solution. Then clean the solution and restart Visual Studio. Then do rebuild (rather than build, though it is cleaned).

Hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: No, It not shared with other. I do many time `rebuild` and open/close vs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got what is my problem. I have a big mistake. I decide write that , where was my problem because maybe it is helpful for other developer.
I fresh installed windows and after that I installed VS 2015. because I did not install IIS , Vs used of IIS Express. this is was my problem. for solve that, I installed IIS and then in **properties** of my project and **Web** section and **server** part  I select `Local IIS` and then Create `virtual directory`. now my problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the Project and click properties. 
Under Build the Active Configuration should be set to Debug.

While running the code with F5 or Play button.
Make sure Debug is selected instead of Release in the drop down next to Play button.

Answer (score 0):

I put myself in a stupid situation.
I remember setting this, and it was a bad idea...
In the Attach to Process dialog, I had the Attach to: set to the older Managed setting 3.5, 3.0, 2.0.
when I should have been using Managed (4.6, 4.5, 4.0). I'm actually using 4.7, but this works for me.
Be sure to match your target framework!