# ASP.NET Web API project stopped running

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My current ASP.NET Web API project simply quit running a couple days ago. No code, not even the code in **Global.asax.cs**, is executing. Some clues:

- The project stopped working after I hopped over to a subcontractor's Git branch. When I hopped back to the master branch, it didn't work.
- The issue is associated with my primary development computer (Windows 10 running in a Parallels environment on OS X). It runs fine on my secondary development machine.
- If I attempt to establish a breakpoint on any line of code after
  starting debug, I get the following error: “The breakpoint will not
  currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” I
  have followed every thread on the following stackoverflow
  [breakpoint not hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo) posting, but have been unable to get it to work.

In addition to implementing the the threads on the stackoverflow
   [breakpoint not hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo) posting, I've tried the following.

- Verified that debug configuration and full debug info are set on all assemblies.
- Manually deleted all bin and obj folders. Cleaned and rebuilt the
  project.
- Rebooted numerous times.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some files leftover from the subcontractor's branch that you don't want? Have you tried discarding all of your changes and then pulling on your good master branch?

Also, I usually find myself receiving the "no symbols loaded" error if my files have changed from the binaries expectation of those files creating a mismatch between what's running and what's displayed in visual studio. Again, making sure you clean the solution and rebuild it or restarting visual studio usually gets me out of trouble.

Comment: user2434455, Great suggestions. As suggested, I did a clean pull on the git repository with the master branch and ran into the same issues (Global.asax.cs not being called and breakpoint not hit error). Everything is pointing to a problematic configuration setting (or settings) in the Visual Studio IDE on my primary development machine. I'm wondering if the act of checking out the subcontractor's branch (and then running debug on that branch) applied those settings to Visual Studio. (It seems unlikely.) It’s also possible that I foolishly applied those settings.

Comment: Is it possible that the issues are tied to the user option files like .suo and csproj.user that the subcontractor checked in by accident?

Comment: No. The subcontractor changed the MyProject.csproj file, which is correctly excluded from .gitignore, but the .suo and csproj.user files are untouched (and included in .gitignore).

Comment: Here's some additional info: The solution is building directly in the **bin** folder associated with the startup project. It's **not** building in **bin/Debug**. I've tried Build > Clean Solution, Build > Rebuild Solution,  toggling the solution build to Release and bac to Build, and manually deleting bin and obj folders and building again. No matter what I do, it's rebuilding directly in the **bin** folder. It's also not showing me any debug info in the Output window when I launch Debug. The Build info appears in the Output window, but no Debug info.