# Remote Debug a CLR Application in Release Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, clr, remote-debugging, release-builds

Did a search for this but didn't find any answers.

I have a CLR (C#, if that's relevant) application running as a Windows service on a remote machine. The running application was built with the standard "Release" configuration. I would like to be able to debug that service remotely from my machine. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

I can attach to the remote process without a problem. When the binary running remotely is that built with the "Debug" configuration, I can set breakpoints, inspect variables and step through code. If the binary is the "Release" version (which is what gets installed for the application), I cannot.

Is there a way to set breakpoints/step through code with a "Release" build of an application? Would I basically have to turn the release build into a debug build (e.g. by enabling the /DEBUG build flag)?

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced button > Debug Info = full.  Don't expect miracles.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that still doesn't seem to let me set breakpoints or step through code. Specifically, when I set a breakpoint, the breakpoint marker says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2155997/17034

Comment: Ah, thanks! That did work for me. Don't know how I didn't come across that previously.