# Visual Studio: "No source file" in Disassembly

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I am quite new to C programming, so I apologize if my question is not very clear, but I came across the following problem in Visual Studio:

I'm trying to debug a function in my project, however when I put a breakpoint in it I get the following message -

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document".

I already checked the proposed solutions in [Fixing "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo) , but none of those worked.

I've cleaned, rebuilt, deleted whatever similar files could be causing a problem, but no improvement. All the symbols are also loading properly.

When I call the function in my code I am getting an output although I can't step in, so I opened the Disassembly and instead of my function, let's call it `func1()`, there's another function with similar name, `_func1()`, and I can step in its assembly, but there's No source file available.

Any ideas how to find out where is `_func1()` located or why on the first place my initial function is not accessed?

Comment: Please read how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have to be more specific , you need screen shots , code etc .

This question would have been ok to ask to a collegue who was looking at your screen. but when you ask on SO , you need to help people see your problem to get any meaningfull reply.

Answer (score 0):

To [enable debugging](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/503d3ded-976e-460e-b5f9-7e03454ed387/debugging-information-cannot-be-found-or-does-not-match?forum=Vsexpressvc): (Also make sure building the programme in debug mode)

> 1) Goto Project->HelloWorld Properties
>
> 2) On the left expand "Configuration Properties"
>
> 3) Expand "C/C++"
>
> 4) On the left, Select "General"
>
> 5) On the right, change "Debug Information Format" to "Program
>   Database For  Edit And Continue (/ZI)"
>
> 5) On the left, Select "Optimization"
>
> 6) On the right, change "Optimization" to "Disabled (/Od)"
>
> 7) On the left, expand "Linker"
>
> 8) On the left, select "Debugging"
>
> 9) On the right, change "Generate Debug Info" to "Yes"
>
> 10) Click ok
>
> 11) Set your breakpoints
>
> 12) Rebuild your application