# Breakpoints not hit if I update my codebehind file (breakpoint will not be hit, the code source is different...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am stuck into an oldish ASP.Net project.
Using VS2012.

The debugger handles breakpoints of all classes fine... but one!

For any reason, I got one of the VB code behind file causing trouble with its breakpoints.
If I run the app without having changed the file, its breakpoints will be correctly hit.
If I ever change anything into this file (even adding a \n character), the next time I will run the app, its breakpoints will be disabled with the too well known warning saying that "breakpoints will not be hit because the source code is different".

How can I have the debugger to accept my changes into this file?
Why is it only causing trouble with this specific file?

I tried to remove my ASP temporary files as suggested in other similar posts.
Did not help.

Thx in advance

EDIT: I actually encountered the very same problem today (1 day later), on a completely different computer / project . On this second project I can clean / rebuild but it does not help. Cleaning the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder is useless too.
This is soo annoying when it happens :(

Comment: A rebuild should sort the issue. If not try cleaning the solution first.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo?rq=1

Comment: For any reason, I do not have a "clean" option into this project. Not sure if it should be available for ASP.Net applications with older frameworks?
At least Build and Rebuild did not help.

Comment: Is the PDB being updated when you build?

Comment: @sr28 Yep, I delete temporary symbols files, I build it again. VS seems to create the files again into "Temporary ASP.NET files" folder again and still mentions that my breakpoints won't be hit.

Comment: @ CathalMF apparently not. The MyAssembly.pdb file into my /bin directory is not  re-generated when I build or run the app. Actually nothing gets updated at all in /bin. Is it normal?

Comment: Have you actually tried running the app and seeing if the breakpoint is hit? As per the linked question, it will only load the necessary symbols when the assembly is needed, so up until that point it will show the breakpoints won't be hit, but when the assembly is loaded they should then show.

Comment: They are definitely not hit :)

Comment: You say that your bin files aren't regenerated when you rebuild. That doesn't sound normal. Have you checked which symbols are loaded?

Comment: @ sr28 : after reading such a suggestion into a similar SO post, I deleted the " Temporary ASP.NET files" folders. After deletion, when I re-run the app, VS creates a new folder into the Temporary ASP.NET files folder and this is where it loads the symbols from.