# Debugging symbols not loaded when using catch..when

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

I have a C# method which contains code like the following:

```
try
{
  // Do whatever
}
catch (Exception2 ex)
{
  // Handle exception 1
}
catch (Exception2 ex)
{
  // Handle exception 1
}
catch (Exception3 ex)
{
  // Handle exception 3
}
```

When I try to debug it, I could place breakpoints normally. However, when one of the catch statements uses the `when` keyword, like:

```
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) when (ex.Message.StartsWith("Whatever message"))
```

no debugging symbol is loaded for that method and I cannot get the debugger to break inside it. Breakpoints inside the method are displayed like:

[image: No debugging symbols loaded for method]

Any idea why this is happening? I am using VS2015 Update 3.

**UPDATE**: One of the comments asked me to show more code, but I literally ended up simplifying my code to the following:

```
using (var model = ContentInventoryModel.Create())
{
  try
  {
    Console.WriteLine("test");
  }
  catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("This email group can"))
  {
  }
}
```

With this code, no symbols are not generated for the method and so I cannot put a break point, say, at `Console.WriteLine` statement. By the time I remove the when `keyword`, symbols get generated and I can put a break point at `Console.WriteLine` statement.

It might be worth mentioning that I am debugging through ReSharper's NUnit Test Runner.

Comment: Are you debugging with full debug symbols (ie. are is the configuration set to debug or to release or maybe something custom)?

Comment: Can you show more code please?I suspect that debugger see that code is unreachable and give you the worning

Comment: @Igor yes, full debug symbols for sure.

Comment: @volkinc see my edit.

Comment: Can you set breakpoints in the try section?

Comment: @BenPen, no I cannot.

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo?noredirect=1&lq=1  It sounds like you might be trying to set breakpoints before any of the symbols are loaded, and that question should solve it.

Comment: @BenPen yes, I have seen that. No actually, other symbols from the even the same file are loaded and I could set break points; it is literally just that method, and only when I use the "when" keyword.

Comment: I'm with @Rafid, check for statements that always exit, ifs that are demonstrably not true I guess.

Comment: The code actually does run correctly and calls made inside the method do actually get called, so it is not a matter of conditions statements that always exit or something like that.