# Breakpoints not hit in specflow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

I'm writing a test case using SpecFlow in C#. When I set appropriate breakpoints and  run the test cases using debugger, all the breakpoints are not hit. When I hover over them, a tip displaying "The breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for the document" is shown. Now, how do I debug the testcases that I have written?

PS: I'm using VS2015

Comment: it may skipped due to condition checking and the block where you put break point may not execute based on the checking. try to put break point on form load and check.

Comment: I tried doing it. Didn't help :(

Comment: Where did you put the breakpoints? In a binding or the feature file? Which unit test provider do you have configured?

Comment: Both in feature and binding files. Doesn't work for both. I have used NUnit

Comment: is the system you are testing running in the same process as the tests, or are you testing a deployed application/web site?

Comment: I'm testing a deployed website

Comment: and are the breakpoints in the code for the deployed website or in the tests?

Comment: @SamHolder In the tests

Comment: have you seen [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem by going to Debug->Options and disabled "Just my Code" option. Then I navigated to symbols and checked "Microsoft Symbol Servers"

Answer (score 0):

Try to build the complete specflow project with specflow definition file as well.Hope it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with VS 2022, so I hope this helps someone.
Spent the last 5 hours trying to figure this out and could not believe how obscure the solution was for me (and simple).

The problem for me was that I hit cancel during the first debug run when VS tried to automatically load all the symbols.

To get VS to reload all the symbols again I needed to make sure of the following in the top panel where all the drop downs are:

- "Debug" was selected
- "Any CPU" was selected
- My project was selected (this was important!)

In Debug > Options > Debugging > General

- Enable Just My Code - Un-ticked

In Debug > Options > Debugging > Symbols

- Microsoft Symbol Server - Ticked
- Load all modules, unless excluded - selected

After that I pressed F5 to start debugging again (or you can hit the SOLID GREEN play button)

When I did this all the symbols started to load again, and I made sure I let it all load.