# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document in Unity

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, breakpoints, coroutine

I am trying to debug a coroutine in Unity using VS2017.

When I attach VS to Unity and set a breakpoint inside the `IEnumerator` method I get the error "Breakpoint will not be hit"

[image]

It is discussed in depth here:
[How do I remedy the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b)

However none of those answers worked for me.

Do you know how to set a breakpoint inside an IEnumerator in VS2017?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known bug in Unity. Here is how to fix this:

**1**.Go to *File* --> *Build Settings...* then select your platform.

**2**.Click on *Player Settings* --> *Other Settings* and change the API Compatibility Level to .NET 2.0.

If it is already set to *.NET 2.0*, change it to *.NET 2.0 Subset* then back to *.NET 2.0*.

**3**.Close and re-open Visual Studio. From Visual Studio, go to *Build* --> *Clean Solution* then *Build* --> *Rebuild Solution*.

Try debugging again and it should work.

---

If the steps above did not work, Go your Project's Library folder then deltete it. Restart both Unity and Visual Studio.

Comment: Solid. This got it! Thanks for sharing some battle wisdom. I knew it was a quirk.

Comment: What about `.NET 4.x`? Is that a source of issues, or did you mean to change to `.NET 2.0` _or above_?

Comment: Well my issue is that the debugger defaults to Native. Deb8ug -> Attach to Debugger -> Select type -> Choose Net 2.0 Then Select Unity Editor running it works and Visual Studio remembers the type

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this happened when **this script was not attached to anything** in the scene, therefore, the breakpoint would never be hit... something unexpected from somebody who works in C++. This is a nice side effect, though.

Comment: Wow, your answer was the only correct one for me, and actually Unity sucks because this code clearly can be reached after stepping through the other class's breakpoint (The one closer to the surface) but they only allowed me to put a breakpoint in that class as opposed to the deeper one.

Answer (score 1):

I spent enough time and found the solution. Go to Build-> Configuration Manager and change Active Solution Configuration to Debug.

Comment: There is no "*Build*" menu on Unity. There is no "*Configuration Manager*" menu on Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: you do not see this menu item because this menu item is hide when project is run. try again without running.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I was using "Attach to process" instead of "Attach to Unity ...". The latter was not available, because the Unity addon for VS failed to install.

Comment: I think I have the exact same problem. I don't see any "Attach to Unity". How do you reinstall the addon?

Comment: They are the same thing

Answer (score 0):

So, i had these too
The unity doesnt know which script tool you are using..

1. In Unity, do Edit -> Preferences.
2. In the Preferences window that opened, choose the External Tools tab.
3. Click on the External Script Editor dropdown.
4. Click on Browse.
5. Select Visual Studio 2017 if not already selected

GoodLuck (;

(:

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. Following steps solved mine.

1. Navigate to ***build->configuration manager***.
2. check for project configuration. If it is set to ***production***, change this value to ***debug***.

Comment: There is no "*build*" menu on Unity. There is no "*configuration manager*" menu on Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: There is a confugration menu and drop down, choose it

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution (workaround).
You need to add the attribute [InitializeOnLoad] to the class.