# VSCode. Debug existing application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-code

I have an aplication WpfApp1 that I just created via VS.

I built it via VS with `DebugType` == full.

Then I open solution folder with VSCode. Set breakpoint, run my app, attach to it, but it say:

> no symbols have been loaded for this document

What am I doing wrong?

This is my configuration:

```
{
    "name": ".NET Core Attach",
    "type": "clr",
    "request": "attach",
    "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
}
```

Yes, I now that I can change `DebugType` to portable and it will work. But I can't do it (I have some resons for it).

Comment: have you executed a google search for the exact error

Comment: Yes. I tried to search it a lot. But no halp. Sorry, I'm rookie in VSCode

Comment: No help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b

Comment: which VS version?

Comment: @StasBZ you have not provided any source code or repository which can allow any other SO user to help you out. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Visual Studio Community edition to debug WPF or other .NET Standard applications. VS Code is meant for cross-platform development, thus the support of the .NET Standard applications is limited to none. E.g. cross-platform development and debugging is supported as well as Mono and .NET Core projects. But WPF is neither of these so you need to use Comunity edition as a minimum.

Here is [more info on the subject](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp).