# VS 2013 the break point will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-debugging

I have one exe and one dll(.net frame work 4.6.1). 
I am mapping the dll to exe and i am able to build both the applications individually and 
mapping to gether in a single solution as well. 
i have placed some break points in both exe and dll. 
when i try to start debugging in exe i am able to hit breakpoints and in dll i am not able to hit my break points.

I am not getting any error but when i move my cursor to breakpoint it is showing as

"the break point will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document" Previously i am able to work with this code and able to debug from exe to dll

Can you please help me on this issue.

I tried in different ways from internet. but my issue din't got resolved.

Comment: look here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b

Comment: @Dinesh, Do you get any detailed messages in your debugger output window? "Mapping" means that you add the dll file as a reference to thie exe project, am I right? Please make sure that two projects using the same .NET Framework and platform target(Any CPU/X86/X64). Enable Microsoft symbols servers under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols. Debug it again. You could also view the Modules windows and find much more detailed information about which assembly impacts the debugging result in your side.

Comment: @Dinesh, Would you mind sharing the latest information about this issue?

Comment: The copy of the DLL you will be debugging is the copy sitting in the EXE's bin folder, not the copy in the DLL's bin folder.  That's why the DLL's IDE doesn't work when you attempt to debug it.  You need to debug the EXE and DLL together under the EXE's IDE.  (I hope that made sense!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are remote debugging like I was this worked for me:

1. Cleaning solution/project whichever applies,
2. Building solution/project,
3. Copying PDB files from .\bin\debug location to the target folder on the host where your program is supposed to execute from.