# How do I remedy the “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” warning?

Tags: visual-studio

in VS 2015 y VS 2017 with project web, not load breakpoint , it did show The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

i Try apply [How do I remedy the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b), but nothing i worked.

the problem was the update packge nuget Web Sharper to last stable versión.

Answer (score 0):

i update versión of package nuget Web Sharper and solution my problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOaq6.jpg)

Clean Solution, and start debug, it load breakpoint without problem

i am sorry, for my english