# Why am I not able to place a debug point in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I tried building the application and run it. 
Got an error. So decided to debug it. 
But when i place the debug point, it's not working.

[image: Scrrenshot]

Comment: Usually the breakpoint not being enabled either means that you're not running in Debug mode, the code isn't running in the application, or you're running an outdated version of the code. Solution: Ensure you're using the Debug configuration, and then clean & rebuild.

Comment: Make sure, your method is is reachable / called.

Comment: If you hover over that break point during run-time it should also tell you why it wont break there.

Comment: Cn you place breakpoints anywhere in the code?

Comment: When I hover over the breakpoint, I get the following message.
"The breakpoint will not currently be hit.No Symbols have been loaded for this document."

Comment: There are many possible reasons for this error and this question has been asked many times in SO. I recommend to read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b).

Comment: That was the first page which popped up when i was searching for the solution. I tried every solution and nothing worked for me. It's still the same. That's why i decided to post it as a separate question.