# In VS2017 breakpoints not hitting sometimes

Tags: c#

I'm using VS2017...my breakpoints are not hitting sometimes...when i put a cursor on breakpoint I'm getting an error called "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.No Symbols have been loaded for this document." Can any one help me on this issue.Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remedy the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b)

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when the code has changed but the build doesn't pick it up.  For example, if the code doesn't match the pdb file, then you'll see this.

Clean the build and then build it again, and try again.