# Why are breakpoints in production assembly not working when debugging test code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I have a web project with a production assembly and a test assembly. When I debug my code in Visal Studio 2017 Community Edition I can set breakpoints. But when I debug my test code then all of a sudden the breakpoints in the production assembly are not working anymore.

The tooltip shows this very familiar error message:

`The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.`

My project structure is that I have a project folder and inside the folder for the UnitTes project.

The namespace of my production assembly is `MyProj.Web` and the namespace of my UnitTest project is `MyProj.Web.UnitTests`.

I've checked if the bin\Debug folder of the test project contains everything needed, it does contain the test dll including pdbs, the production dll also including pdbs. I have checked if the code actually runs in this folder and it does.

I'm suspecting I've done something wrong here, but what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remedy the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b)

Comment: To debug Unit Tests you must do either: Right click on the test method > Run Debug Test or (top Menu) Test > Debug > All Tests

Comment: @LucaCorradi That's really not my issue.

Comment: Clarification: I am hitting the breakpoints in my test assembly, but not in my production assembly. When I start the app via F5 I can also hit the breakpoints in my production assembly

Comment: @tweray I've looked at this post. When I debug my test code and open the Modules window, I can see that the pdbs for my production assembly have not been loaded. When I try to load it manually I can select it in the browse dialog but then I'm unable to add it: `A matching symbol file was not found in this folder.`, after I selected it?!? But more to the point, I've never had this problem before, I must have done sth wrong with my project structure

Answer (score 0):

If you are publishing your files before attaching the debugger, make sure the assemblies are being built with the correct Debug configuration

[image]

Also Check in Project Properties for each project under the Build Tab, in the advanced section pictured below, that "Full" is selected from the Debugging Information drop down. This will ensure that you are able to attach a debugger to the assembly.

[image]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the upper dialog, I'm working on a web project, but right now everything's local. The second dialog, I have already checked this before, that lloks all good, but my problem persists. I think I may have done something wrong with either the overall structure (folder-wise or namespace-wise, I've fiddled around with the namespaces after setting everything up)