# Unable to debug in-process web project (ASP.NET Core Module)

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I'm experimenting with the **ASP.NET Core Module** introduced in ASP.NET Core v2.2.0, specifically the in-process hosting. I am able to get it to work in production, but while developing, Visual Studio warns me that breakpoints won't be hit because no symbols have been loaded for the document.
I suspect this has to do with the in-process mode, Visual Studio doesn't know how to attach itself to the service (`w3wp.exe`).

Does anyone know what I'm missing? As soon as I switch to out-of-process hosting, the breakpoints work as they should.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2

[image]

Comment: are you running debug mode?

Comment: have you tried manually attaching to w3wp.exe?

Comment: @JohnB No, but I don't want to have to manually attach every time I want to test my app, I just want to press F5 and it should work as normal.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Make sure that you download and instal latest ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 Version mismatch can lead to unexpected issues.

Answer (score 0):

> (I can't put it in a simple comment as I don't have needed reputation)

Maybe have a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b) if you haven't.
Personnaly, last (and only) time I had this "error" on a breakpoint, I had to install again VS.

Answer (score 0):

I got a same issue. What I noticed is that in runtime value of modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" is changed to modules="AspNetCoreModule" in my Web.Config file.