# Visual Studio - Symbols not loaded from other class lib

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I recently changed my solution from

- 1 project with many folders inside

to

- 1 app runner and a few Console Library

But, now my breakpoints aren't enabled (No symbols have been loaded) in those .cs files that are coming from those class libraries.

Only breakpoints in my app runner (entry point) work correctly.

Any idea?

Here's my config
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remedy the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b)

Comment: Console application or class library? If you have added class library project then you need to add Projects from References. Go to References -> right click -> Add references -> Projects -> select your project name from it