# Unable to debug VSTO solution using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, ms-office, vsto

I have created one tool using VSTO , but i am unable to debug the same in VS-2017 community version , it is VSTO code, in which I have written the code in C#, which interact with MS Office.

I have a word exe as the startup project and as soon as I run the application n it breaks stating application is in break mode, seems like it is unable to load symbols. I have enabled debugging in the solution properties and set it to full.
I have also enabled the debugging of native code.

I tried to  delete the bin/debug folder and rebuild the solution, It loads symbols and after that the word instance which starts hangs.

Kindly help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably one of your references can't be loaded or absent. So, try to check all References first.

However, there are a lot of reasons why your breakpoints can't be hit. You may find similar postings there:

- [How do I remedy the “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b)