# Web API caching DLL and symbol file for one controller only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

One of the Web API controller call is being cached.  Old dll and symbols are being used, so when I debug I get "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning.  As soon as I hit other Web API controllers in the same debugging session the latest dll and symbols are used so I can debug.

I am not using any caching or GAC on this project.  I have tried clean > rebuild, restarting VS 2015 and restarting the computer without resolution.

This is a .NET Framework 4.5 project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b?

Comment: Mohammad, yes without success.  I think my case is different in that only one controller call is being cached.  All others are loading current DLLs and symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some old files in your temporary folder.

When you run the application, it will create a "cache" in a folder like this one :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

there will multiple folders there, one for each application you're running. 
Stop the application in IIS, then find the folder where the cached files are and delete that folder. Then run the app again, it will use the latest dlls.

The Clean option will not remove those files for you.

It's either Framework or Framework64, depending if you're building it as a 64 bit application or not.