# How do I fix this error "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

When trying to debug any of my projects in my solution, none of the breakpoints gets triggered, and I get the following warning message:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

It seems to be specific to this solutions, which consists of 6 projects. A week ago this was still working.

I have tried the folowing:

1. Enabling/Disabling "Enable Just My Code".
2. Cleaned and rebuilt the entire solution.
3. Cleaned and rebuilt each project individually.
4. Deleted the Bin and Obj folders in each project, and rebuild.
5. Cleared the "SymbolCache" folder, and rebuild.
6. Repaired and Updated Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition).
7. Updated all packages in the solution.
8. Checked that all my projects are set to Debug and Any CPU.

I double-checked that there are no build errors in any of the projects. The application, in general, works fine.

I've tried many solutions I found in forums. The one thing I did notice, is that the Crystal Reports modules have a status message of `Cannot find or open the PDB file` next to all the DLL's. for example:

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll    C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine\13.0.3500.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
>   No    No  Cannot find or open the PDB file. 72    13.00.21.2533   2017/08/31 02:10 PM 0BCD0000-0BD30000   [15568] iisexpress.exe  [2]
>   /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132102498773678728

I tried uninstalling Crystal Reports, and commenting any code or references to these DLL's. This makes no difference.

The strange thing is that when I open other solutions, the debugger works fine.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as the error message says you don't have the program database file for the code you want to debug. You should check your debugging options and the locations where you load the pdbs from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remedy the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b)

Comment: If you are compiling in debug mode then you need to copy the debug files(pdb) as well.  Are you trying to attach to process?  3rd party products will not ship with pdb file.   The only other way to possibly debug into CrystalReports would be to use DotPeek from JetBrains...

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I think I figured out what was causing the error. It seems that Visual Studio for some reason is copying my Project files to the the follwoing location:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\...

For example:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\aa278a60\6d6ea15b\assembly\dl3\4c39ffcf\e162b0f9_b352d501\Pps.Web.dll

This location also contains the PDB file. How do you specify the location of the PDB files?

Comment: What's the project name of your app, Pps.web? I'm not sure what you mean `copy project files to xxx`, the xx.csproj file?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to delete all bin and all object directories in your working path. I had just now the same problem (again), but after I deleted the dirs, it worked as usual.

Comment: Hi, @peter70, thank you for the suggestion. I have a solution with 6 separate projects in them. Some of the projects depend on others. For example I have all my Data Models in one project, My Admin code in aother, Customers, etc...

The issue was that the DLL files for my projects was not being copied to my startup project. I solved it by point the Output Paths of all projects to my startup project.

Comment: @JacoAF that makes sense ;-)

Comment: One thing to check is that you have the solutions configuration drop down set to "Debug" and not "Release".